# getActivity().findViewById returns null, called from fragment onActivityCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I am following the [contacts provider lesson on retrieving contacts](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) and displaying them using fragments. For reference, I have set the API level to 16 (Android 4.1).

I have mostly followed this tutorial to the letter, with a few notable exceptions. For example, I import from `mypackage.R` rather than `android.R`.

My problem is in my `onActivityCreated` handler in my `ListContactsFragment`:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Initializes the loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    // Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity

    View mContactsListView = 
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);
    mContactsList = (ListView) mContactsListView;

    // Gets a CursorAdapter
    mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.contacts_list_item,
            null,
            FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS,
            0);
    // Sets the adapter for the ListView
    mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    // Set the item click listener to be the current fragment.
    mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

`View mContactsListView` is null, meaning `findViewById` didn't work.

My parent activity is a default one created by eclipse. To this, I have done two things:

1. Replaced `import android.app.Activity` with `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` to prevent the `ClasscastException` that happens if you don't.
2. Imported my fragment into the XML.

My `activity_list_contacts.xml` looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ListContactsActivity" >

    <fragment android:name="mypackage.ListContactsFragment"
              android:id="@+id/contacts_list_view"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the matching activity, just in case:

```
public class ListContactsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_contacts);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_contacts, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and `contacts_list_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong for `findViewById` not to find my view?

Things I have tried (most of these are accepted answers on questions that almost look like a duplicate to this one):

- Reading the document I copied and pasted from word for word.
- Trying to `getView().findViewById()` as suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602591/getactivity-returning-null-from-fragment). This also returns null.
- using `findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);` instead as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100472/257111). This doesn't return null; instead it causes a `ClassCastException` in that `android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout` could not be cast to `android.widget.ListView`.
- I read that sometimes the fragment callback for creation occurs before being attached to the activity. So, I added the handler to the `onAttach` method like so:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);

      View mContactsListView = activity.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);
      mContactsList = (ListView) mContactsListView;

      // Gets a CursorAdapter
      mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
              getActivity(),
              R.layout.contacts_list_item,
              null,
              FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS,
              0);
      // Sets the adapter for the ListView
      mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

      // Set the item click listener to be the current fragment.
      mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  }
  ```

  You guessed it - still null.

So at this point I am a little lost. I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong (please request additional info in comments if I have not provided enough)?
2. Is it preferable to leave the adapter setup in `onAttach`, or where the tutorial says.

Comment: If you are using an id from the Android framework, it should be used as `android.R.id.*`. Is `TO_IDS` defined as `private final static int[] TO_IDS = { android.R.id.text1 }`?

Comment: @vikram yep, it is, as a member of the fragment class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I follow the tutorial at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html#NameMatch) and encountered the very same problem.

Finally i noticed that in this part:

```
// Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity
    mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contact_list_view);
```

it seems trying to find a `View`, but passing a `Layout id` as argument.

The [View | android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) says :

> View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of the tree you are searching.

So, i changed the `ListView id` in the `contacts_list_view.xml` to a unique one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView ...
android:id="@+id/contacts_listview_a_unique_id_here"
... />
```

then try to find it with:

```
        mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contacts_listview_a_unique_id_here);
```

and it works ( in the `onActivityCreated` callback).

- About the cast exception:
  As [hierarchyviewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) shows, the tree is like this:
  [image: hierarchyviewer sc]
  so if you `findViewById` passing root element of the view, like in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100273/findviewbyidr-layout-skeleton-activity-returns-null/5100472#5100472), it will return `NoSaveStateFrameLayout`, which is not the child `ListView` you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go and let you know how I get on :)

Answer (score 2):

`getActivity().findViewById()` looks for the id you provide as parameter in the hierarchy of views of the `Activity`. Probably the `ListView` is returned by `onCreateView` of your fragment. If you want to perform a `findViewById` on the fragment views hierarchy, you have to call `getView().findViewById()`. In this case, since you are extending `ListFragment`, to retrieve the `ListView`, as for the `ListActivity`, you have to use `getListView();` another analogy with the `ListActivity` is the id of the `ListView` inside the xml file ( `android:id="@android:id/list"`)

Comment: I know this is a old question, but hopefully you can clear something up for me. I asked a question about a hour ago, I think I've resolved the issue by calling `getActivity.findViewById`, but the view that I'm referring to is a fragment, which doesn't make sense, here is a link to my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736715/view-returning-null-when-trying-to-apply-margin-using-layoutparams

Answer (score 1):

Note that `ListFragment` has a `getListView()` method to return the `ListView` widget instance.

Developer docs: [ListFragment.getListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#getListView%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

@theme propose a solution, but in order to use android's inner listview here is another way. Because in your "contacts_list_view.xml" file your're using android's inner listview with id=@android:id/list. And in your code you can refer to the list view with findViewById(android.R.id.list), so your onActivityCreated will be like this:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);//(R.layout.fragment_contact_list);
    mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contact_item_list,null, FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS, 0);
    mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
}
```

Hope it helps, it's good the android developer guide contains such "bug" so that we can be familiar with the api.