# findViewById in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, findviewbyid

I am trying to create an ImageView in a Fragment which will refer to the ImageView element which I have created in the XML for the Fragment. However, the `findViewById` method only works if I extend an Activity class. Is there anyway of which I can use it in Fragment as well?

```
public class TestClass extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

The `findViewById` method has an error on it which states that the method is undefined.

Comment: Use ButterKnife viewbinding library for android. Also demonstrate how it’s work, how to integrate and use in your android app development to make your development faster.

Comment: 'Some' time has passed but you still haven't accepted an answer. Can you select the answer that helped you most so this can be marked as answered?

Comment: It is encourages to use Data Binding orang View Binding instead manual findViewById

Answer (score 1612):

Use [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) or the View parameter from implementing the  `onViewCreated` method. It returns the root view for the fragment **(the one returned by `onCreateView()` method)**. With this you can call `findViewById()`.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.foo);
    // or  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.foo); 
}
```

As `getView()` works only after `onCreateView()`, you **can't use it inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` methods** of the fragment .

Comment: Note: it's works only after onCreateView(). So, you can't use this in onCreate()

Comment: so what is the function I can override to implement this if onCreate is not the right place ?

Comment: This doesn't help if the `ImageView` is coming from the inflated layout - see my answer for details. Otherwise, onCreateView is the right place to do this @N-AccessDev

Comment: The best place to do this the onViewCreated method

Comment: you can't use getActivity and findViewById there in onCreate() or onCreateView either because they both come before onActivityCreated() which is when you are guaranteed that the activity view heirarchy has been created.

Comment: The documentation states that `onActivityCreated()` is the recommended place to find and store references to your views. You **must** clean up these stored references by setting them back to `null` in `onDestroyView()` or you will leak the `Activity`.

Comment: It works but I don't get why: I understand that `findViewById()` works in the scope of an Activity object because it is defined in the Activity class. 
As explained in this answer, in order to use it in a fragment we need to call it on `getView()` but... why? Isn't `getView()` just going to return a View as opposed to an Activity? ... I understand `getActivity.findViewById()` but `getView.findViewById()` ???

Comment: `getView` might return null. LeffelMania has a better solution.

Comment: @Locutus `You must clean up these stored references by setting them back to null in onDestroyView() or you will leak the Activity` reference please?

Comment: @cricket_007  getview work in onCreateview() in fragment

Comment: @RobbyPatel There's no possible way it can. It will return null.

Comment: @cricket_007  here is another issue my code is completely good

Comment: Actually you can make it work inside `onCreateView()` if you capture the view instance as 
`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);` and do
`rootView.findViewById()` after that

Comment: @NoLuck, Yes, but that's what the other answers are for

Comment: @MuhammadBabar  reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: What if part of creating my Activity (`onCreate()`) that contains my Fragment depends on the UI elements of the Fragment?  Where can I initialize my Fragment's views so that they are initialized after the Fragment has been committed but before the Activity's `onCreate()` is finished?
Or instead should I be initializing my Activity's UI in a method after `onCreate()`, like `onResume()`?

Comment: Good information on the difference between onViewCreated and onCreateView here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38718205/7715734

Comment: I would recommend using `view.findViewById` since this has a built-in NonNull annotation, thus no warnings to handle null pointer exceptions

Comment: mine giving null. I have  posted  a  new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67313132/6854117)

Comment: Important to note is onViewCreated and NOT onCreateView or else app will crash saying unable to inflate.

Answer (score 670):

You need to inflate the Fragment's view and call `findViewById()` on the `View` it returns.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
     return view;
}
```

Comment: When you do V.findViewById(R.id.someid),surely that will only work for all the widgets that are in the inflated view. What if the imageView he is trying to inflate is outside the inflated view?

Comment: Then the class that "owns" and inflated the imageView needs to provide public access to it. That is very bad practice though. Fragments should only have access to the UI elements present in their layout.

Comment: Note that findViewById has to be called on the view that is inflated, not on getView()

Comment: For future readers: this method does not work. It just raises a android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong in your code (updating UI from a background thread), not mine.

Comment: Thanks, it was useful. As unrelated comment: try to stick to Java naming conventions in your code. "V" does not look like a variable name in Java.

Comment: This should be the right answer. The accepted one leaves you with `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This should be the most voted, since is the correct answer. The one by advantej is wrong, since the layout hasn't been inflated before the `getView()`

Comment: @Raunak You are correct `inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourdialogfragment, null).findViewById(R.id.someidfromfragmentdialog)` will only return widgets that are in the fragment. If you want to get widgets from the host activity (the activity that spawned the DialogFragment) you have to use `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.someidfromhostlayout)`

Comment: @Raunak Thanks for the comment. I was wondering out aloud why the accepted answer does not use the view returned by the inflater. This discussion has clarified my doubt.

Comment: Casting to ImageView is redundant.

Answer (score 156):

Inside `Fragment` class you will get [onViewCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,android.os.Bundle)) override method where you should always initialize your views as in this method you get view object using which you can find your views like :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    view.findViewById(R.id.yourId).setOnClickListener(this);

    // or
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourId).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Always remember in case of Fragment that `onViewCreated()` method will not called automatically if you are returning null or `super.onCreateView()` from `onCreateView()` method.
It will be called by default in case of `ListFragment` as `ListFragment` return `FrameLayout` by default.

Note: you can get the fragment view anywhere in the class by using `getView()` once `onCreateView()` has been executed successfully.
 i.e.

```
getView().findViewById("your view id");
```

Comment: I am surprised not a lot of people have upvoted this response--this is the correct way to setup listeners on fragments... Perhaps this was a new development in the API.

Comment: Using `view` passed to `onViewCreated` still causes `NullPointerException` but using `getActivity()` is fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: @dVaffection It may be that you are not returning a non null view in onCreateView() lifecycle method of fragment. Now in case of getActivity you are getting views from your activity rather than fragment main view depends upon what id you are passing.
Please check are you returning a non null view from onCreateView or not? 
Then let me know.

Comment: @AnkurChaudhary I return view from `onCreateView` method. I've just debugged and it turns out there is a layout (in my case `FrameLayout`). That being said when I try to find an element it returns `null`. Why is it happening?

Comment: @dVaffection can you please share your class of fragment and corresponding layout.

Comment: @AnkurChaudhary You can find it here https://github.com/dVaffection/YAGL/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/dvlab/yagl

Comment: In particular `ListActivityFragment.java` line 63 `(FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.floating_new_item);`

Comment: @dVaffection i have gone through your code and as you are returning super.oncreateView() which returns null. Another point is when you return null from onCreateView, onViewCreated() method will not be called automatically. Yes you can call it manually. Means onViewCreated will not be called if you are returning null or super method calling. That's why when you are trying to get any view from fragment it's returning null to you.

Comment: @AnkurChaudhary What you're saying is valid if you inherit from `Fragment`, in my case I extend `ListFragment` which actually returns `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @dVaffection I checked the layout that ListFragment is using and there is no such view with the id 'floating_new_item'. So it's pretty clear that if you will try to access such field which is not in your layout then it'll return null. Now let me know that is your activity having this id field or not as you are using fragment_list layout in your activity.

Answer (score 70):

What is required of `imageView` - are we passing it back as the view, or merely saving a reference for later?

Either way, if the `ImageView` is coming from the inflated layout, the correct way to do this would be:

```
public class TestClass extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: How then would you update imageView from ListFragment?  Would this require FragmentManager?  In other words, how can you update the imageView in a detail fragment from a separate class's onListItemClick?

Comment: You would either save a reference to the imageView somewhere handy, or  fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.my_image) when you need it. In a ListFragment, assuming the image is in a list item, you would generally create a reference holder with the setTag/getTag methods of the list view item in your Adapter's getView method - there are many examples of how to do this.

Comment: @MattJenko, can you share more details or sample how to do have working solution when the inflated layout is used? for instance, i have an viewpager2 with tablayout (4 tabs ) mediated, and I am inflating the edittext views in fragment, and I need to access the editext for each viewpager2's view from main activity. How to do it exactly?

Answer (score 54):

Get first the fragment view and then get from this view your ImageView.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: So, does onCreate method is useful in a Fragment ?

Comment: onCreateView creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.onCreate is called to do initial creation of the fragment. Indeed, it depends on what you write in these methods.

Comment: Okay, but how can i declare variable in the onCreate ? Because the View is inside the onCreateView method .

Comment: @Tsunaze did you ever find out how to do this from the onCreate method?

Answer (score 33):

Inside **`Fragment`** class we get `onViewCreated()` override method where we should always initialize our views because in this method we get **`view`** object. Using this object we can find our views like below:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //initialize your view here for use view.findViewById("your view id")
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

You could also do it in the `onActivityCreated` Method.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Like they do here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html **(deprecated in API level 28)**

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.foo);
```

and

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.foo);
```

are possible.

Comment: Note that API 28 introduces requiereActivity(), requireView(), requireViewById().

Answer (score 21):

`getView()` will give the root view

```
View v = getView().findViewByID(R.id.x);
```

Answer (score 19):

You can override onViewCreated() which is called right after all views had been inflated. It's the right place to fill in your Fragment's member `View` variables. Here's an example:

```
class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    private Gallery gallery;

    (...)

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        gallery = (Gallery) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(adapter);
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The method **getView()** wont work on fragments outside OnCreate and similar methods.

You have two ways, pass the view to the function on the oncreate (what means you can only run your functions when the view is being created) or set the view as a variable:

```
private View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contatos, container, false);
}

public void doSomething () {
    ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.someId);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

First inflate layout of Fragment then you can  use findviewbyId.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
             ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
             return view;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
EditText name = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText add = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

Answer (score 11):

Agreed with calling `findViewById()` on the View.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.my_image);

    return V;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Note :

**From API Level 26, you also don't need to specifically cast the result of findViewById as it uses inference for its return type.**

So now you can simply do,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
     ImageView imageView =  view.findViewById(R.id.my_image); //without casting the return type
     return view;
}
```

Comment: Without casting thing explained helped me.

Comment: I suggest to combine this answer with one mentioning deprecation of getView() in API 28.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
imagebutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);

imageview = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
```

it will work

Answer (score 9):

Using `getView()` returns the view of the fragment, then you can call `findViewById()` to access any view element in the fragment view.

Comment: the view is not the activity

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation on API level 11

Reference, in Back Stack
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

short code

```
/**
 * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
 * instance number.
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
    View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this it works for me

```
public class TestClass extends Fragment {
    private ImageView imageView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
        findViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void findViews(View view) {
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this code **here** is okay. Your edits to the other are not.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't quite understand your English, but everything is fixed now. I have nothing to show you.

Answer (score 7):

```
ImageView imageView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                     ViewGroup container, 
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
 imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
 return view;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1) Declare your layout file.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, 
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
}
```

2)Then, get the id of your view

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to implement this is as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        return rootView
}
```

In this way, the rootView can be used for each control defined in the xml layout and the code is much cleaner in this way.

Comment: i thinked this could be posiible, but  , it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

Try This:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_image);

return v;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
private View myFragmentView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayoutId, container, false);
myView = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.myIdTag)
return myFragmentView;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for the field. You can always call `getView()` later

Answer (score 4):

Use gradle [skeleton plugin](https://github.com/fuzz-productions/skeleton), it will automatically generate the view holder classes with the reference to your layout.

```
public class TestClass extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyLayout myLayout = new MyLayout(inflater, container, false);
        myLayout.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage);
        return myLayout.view;
    }
}
```

Now assuming you had an `ImageView` declared in your `my_layout.xml` file, it will automatically generate myLayout class for you.

Answer (score 4):

I like everything to be structured. You can do in this way.

First initialize view

```
private ImageView imageView;
```

Then override OnViewCreated

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        findViews(view);
    }
```

Then add a void method to find views

```
private void findViews(View v) {
    imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.img);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//here you can do it by
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apple, container, 
 false);
    ist = view.findViewById(R.id.linearLink);
    second = view.findViewById(R.id.linearPhone);
    return view;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `findViewById()` with the **Activity Object** you get inside your `public void onAttach(Activity activity)` method inside your Fragment.

Save the Activity into a variable for example:

In the **Fragment class**:
`private Activity mainActivity;`
In the `onAttach()` method:
`this.mainActivity=activity;`

Finally execute every findViewById through the vairable:
`mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.TextView);`

Answer (score 3):

Inside onCreateView method

1) first you have to inflate the layout/view you want to add
eg. LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
```

2) Then you can find your imageView id from layout

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
```

3)return the inflated layout

```
return ll;
```

Comment: This is identical to LeffelMania's answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more method called onViewCreated.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to inflate the view

```
public class TestClass extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    return v
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

In fragments we need a view of that window so that we make a onCreateView of this Fragment.

Then get the view and use it to access each and every view id of that view elements..

```
  class Demo extends Fragment
    {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_fragment, container,false);
            ImageView imageview=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) What does this add to other answers? 2) You seem to have answered twice

Answer (score 3):

Layout inflater comes into picture here. Layout inflater is a class that make us able to use the XML views in java code. So you can inflate the root xml view in variable v with the following code. And then using v, you can find the child views of the root view v.

```
public class TestClass extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`getView()` works only *after* `onCreateView()` completed, so invoke it from `onPostCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use such things is to use butterknife
By this you can add as many Onclciklisteners just by @OnClick() as described below:

```
public class TestClass extends Fragment {
    @BindView(R.id.my_image) ImageView imageView;
    @OnClick(R.id.my_image)
    public void my_image_click(){
        yourMethod();
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(getActivity,view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why down voted, if you use this, you can use multiple onclicks also in on statement.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple way to do:

```
 @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
            return fragmentView;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
     return view;
}
```

Notice if you use `getView()` method it might cause `nullPointerException` because it returns the rootview and it will be some view after `onCreateView()` method.

Answer (score -2):

### Timing of transaction after .commit() may also cause this issue

I got the same issue (View in a  Fragment could not be reached). The reason turned out to be, that - immediately after (FragmentTransaction)**.commit()** -, the  View had not been activated in the UI. *There is no guarantee **when**, after .commit(), the transaction takes place; it's only queued.* So I added a (FragmentManager)**.executePendingTransactions()** to force the transaction to be done. After that, referencing the View works as expected !