# Android - Multiple fragments based on the same class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developping an Android application in which I need to have multiple fragments based on the same class inside a `FragmentActivity`. For now, my code is mostly based on [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html) from the official doc, except I instantiate the same class for each fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), MyFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), MyFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"), MyFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Tab 4"), MyFragment.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
}
```

The class `MyFragment` is pretty simple:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
                return null;
        }

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

I simplified the layout inflated by the Fragment class to a simple TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test_textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/some_default_value"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, the thing is, I would like to ba able to modify the value of `test_textView1` separately in each fragment, **after** they have been instantiated. My problem is that I don't manage to access to the elements of the layout of a fragment. I cannot directly use the `findViewById()` method since it would affect all the fragments.
Inside the `TabsAdapter` class, I tried to access a single fragment, and then access its View by doing the following:

```
getItem(number).getView();
```

but it returns `null`. (`getItem()` returns a correct fragment but `getView()` returns null).

I also read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android), but if I declare a TextView in my `Fragment`, add a method `setTextView(String s)` and call it from the `FragmentActivity` it generates a NullPointerException.

So, is there a specific way to separately access layout items in my fragments? Thanks!

Comment: You could programmaticly add the TextView in your MyFragment class instead, making a TextView parameter for the class, then it's just getItem(n).myTextView.setText("Text");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I started all over again and based my code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view), and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you have fragments: frag1, frag2, frag3, etc. you can use frag1.getView().findViewById() to limit the scope to just that fragment since each fragment extends the same class.

Example:

```
TextView frag1text = (TextView)frag1.getView().findViewById();
```

Comment: fragX.getView() returns null. This is weird because fragX is not null. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Is this after or before you complete the fragment transaction?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView of your fragments remember to save a pointer to the view. Then you'll always be able to say myPointer.findViewById(); in order to get a subitem of your view.

Comment: I tried that already but when I try to access myPointer outside onCreateView, it is always null. I think this is linked to the lifecycle of a fragment.

Comment: Yes it is, but why would you like to change something that isn't displayed? Why not just change a String variable and then display the string variable with through a textview?