# findViewById not recognised in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [findViewById in fragment android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android)

I am currently working on android project and trying to get fragments working. The fragment part is working but I'm trying to control UI components, on a standard activity I can use something like

```
TextView txtMyTextBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_box)
```

I am extending the class by ListFragment but when why I try the same code as above I get the following error

> The method findViewById(int) is undefined

Why doesn't this work. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method is not defined in the Fragment class which is where I assume you're calling it.  You have to use it on the View that the Fragment is showing.  This is the same view that you return in `onCreateView()` and you can retrieve it by `getView()`.  Thus, `TextView txtMyTextBox = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.my_text_box)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you use fragments, you should override the onCreateView method.

Here is an exemple :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_FRAGMENT_LAYOUT, null);

        TextView txtMyTextBox = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_text_box)

        return v;
    }
```