# How to avoid the Null Pointer Exception when calling a method from a fragment in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So I have created a Fragment for my app. In the fragment, I have an `EditText` field created through the xml file (whose id is `myText`). Now in my Java class of this fragment, I am creating a reference to this text field by using the command:

```
EditText myText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

However, I get a warning on this statement saying:

```
Method invocation `getView().findViewById(R.id.myText)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'.
```

Also, when I run the app, it terminates prematurely due to the same `NullPointerException`. I did the exact same thing except without using a fragment (that is, I created an `EditText` field in the xml file of my main activity) and created a reference to it in the Java file using the command:

```
EditText myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

and it works perfectly.

So my question is, why does this work in the second case and not in the first? How do I make it work in the first case?

Comment: This question is **not** duplicate of *What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?*. It's pure Android question about getting `View`, not about variable, which has not been initialized. **I'm voting to reopen it.**

Comment: @DamianKozlak, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536125/findviewbyid-within-fragment

Comment: Do still you think that it's not duplicate? ;-)

Comment: @piotrek1543 Please read carefuly what I wrote. By marking question as duplicate you must link question, where it has been already answered. Question *What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?* marked by Hrundi **does not contain answer**, which answers James Bond question direcly. Links provided by you are better and these may be linked at the top of this post, under *This question already has an answer here:* text :)

Comment: @piotrek1543 Also, James Bond was trying to do something on his own  - by using `getView()`, so he get `NullPointerException` for the reason that he was trying to find component in wrong view, so he (probably) needed explanation why `getView()` is wrong in this situation too.

Comment: @DamianKozlak the OP is not wondering why the NPE occurs, which is what they should do first. The marked duplicate will help them do that.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) from the official Android documentation.

When you create a fragment, you inflate the fragment's view using the `LayoutInflater` provided in `onCreateView`

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
```

To access your views in this layout, you can call `findViewById(R.id.yourId);` on the view that was returned by `inflater.inflate`

All together it should look something like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
    EditText myText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.myText);

    ...
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because using `getView()` you may not get view of inflated layout, which contains desired component. Also there is an option that you are trying to `getView()`, while view has not been yet created, so this will result in NPE too.

You should initialize your view, where you are sure that this `View` contains component which you are looking for. In `Fragment` it will be

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    EditText myText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myText);
    return v;
}
```