# Play fullscreen video in webview using iframe

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I've been trying to play fullscreen video using an iframe but I can't make it work. Here is the code I'm using:

```
public String getHTML() {


    String html= "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" align=\"center\"" +
            "src=\"http://www2.whatsupcams.com/wucf_mod_2.php?id=si_bohinj2&autoplay=true\">" +
            "</iframe>";


    return html;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_webcam);
    mWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setFocusable(true);
    mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    String data_html = getHTML();
    mWebView.loadData(data_html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
```

The video works but the problem is that I can't make the iframe fit the screen, it's either too small or to big for an HD screen. It's too big with the current configuration, looking in stackoverflow I found that:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Could do the trick, but it makes the image too small, is there a way to make the iframe use the whole screen? I was thinking something like setting the zoom to fit the screen because when I double tap on the iframe the zoom looks like the appropriate to fill the screen. Thanks.

Comment: did you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16199649/1677824 ??

Comment: Thanks! it works, but is there a way to launch the full screen event when the user clicks on play button like in IOS?

Comment: i guess that is not possible, please upvote my answer it has worked for you :)

Comment: @dan87 How you can load HTML `<iframe>` in @Akhil code.Please share your code.I also want to do same like you.