# Making an embed video full screen in android webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview, html5-video, fullscreen

I want to take an embedded video from a website and then play it full screen, like the default android browser does. I have been looking all over trying to find the solution but I am coming up short. I have the video playing fine, but I want it to pop out and go full screen. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Webview app won't let video player go full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796661/android-webview-app-wont-let-video-player-go-full-screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a hassle for me trying to make it work in fullscreen mode until I found [this project](https://github.com/akhgupta/WebviewVideo) on github that works like a charm.

This a copy of it.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
    private View mCustomView;
    private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (inCustomView()) {
                hideCustomView();
                return true;
            }

            if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
           onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mCustomView = null;
        }
    }

    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient); This line is appearing null, any tips?

Comment: `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);` Check that the id is right