# Show Video in WebView Issue

Tags: java, android, video, webview, fullscreen

I got the video to show in a Webview in landscape mode..

But somehow the video doesn't cover full screen. There is a white part at the bottom of the video which is a bit annoying..

I've tried using 
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

But they don't seem to fix it.

How do I make the video that played in a WebView cover the entire device screen?

Comment: Maybe this link help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796661/android-webview-app-wont-let-video-player-go-full-screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview

Comment: Hi @AbbasNikzad I already look into that.. but my video is not HTML5, it's a live stream in MJPEG format

Answer (score 0):

if your video is live stream you don't need `webview` !

I prefer using **Vitamio** `Library` to stream and show inside your app!

---

If you want to perform HLT (HTTP Live Stream) on Android 2.1 and higher you may use the vitamio library.

Site at: (http://www.vitamio.org/).

Here is code example: The main layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:paddingLeft="2px" android:paddingRight="2px"
            android:paddingTop="2px" android:paddingBottom="2px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

            <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/VideoView">               
            </io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the Class:

```
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class LiveStrimingTestActivity extends Activity{

    VideoView videoView;

    private void test_2(){
        String httpLiveUrl = "http://aj.lsops.net/live/aljazeer_en_high.sdp/playlist.m3u8";   
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        test_2();             
    }     
}
```

Comment: How would I use it.. can you provide more details? Thanks

Comment: Hi Abbas, Thanks so much for the helpful response. Do you have any way that I could contact you to ask privately such as Skype?

Comment: i have only telegram , you can send me message in telegram by my id : http://telegram.me/ellip01

Comment: I downloaded the app but find nowhere to add your id