# Enabling fullscreen video in webview

Tags: android, video, webview, fullscreen

I have enabled video suport in my webview but, in the youtube videos, there is no fullscreen icon.

In the Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link ;

[Web-view with full you-tube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796661/android-webview-app-wont-let-video-player-go-full-screen)

You need to implement showCustomView & hideCustomView method of WebChromeClient, also You need android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your AndroidManifest File. I am posting my sample project here. What i have done is kept one Framelayout(customContainer) in my main.xml, and adding view received in showCustomView here, and removing it in onHide. Also hiding/showing webview accordingly. Below code works perfectly on device.