# Get view of Fragment from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `FragmentActivity` where I add a `Fragment`. 
Depending on some situation, I want to access `Buttons` from that fragment's layout and change click listeners of them.

What I do is:

```
View view = myFragment.getView();
Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
```

But the `view` variable is always `null`.

How can I get the view of the activity?

Comment: Is myFragment added and visible?

Comment: Note that you're calling `findViewById()` on your activity's view hierarchy, not `view`'s.

Comment: When you do : `Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);`, you try to find out the button for your current view which is not your `fragment view` . Hence it's not working as expected .

Comment: Yes, it is. I am trying to implement SlidingMenu feature. Actually, everything worked fine before adding this feature.

Comment: @laalto, sorry, mistyped there. Edited the post.

Comment: did you do that in method onActivityCreated ?

Comment: @VolodymyrYatsykiv, no, in onCreate() of FragmentActivity

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to access your component and set some data, I suggest you to make a method inside the fragment like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    public void setSettings(){
        Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    }
}
```

Comment: getView() might return null and it does so in many cases. If I call setSettings from Activity's OnCreate method the exception will be thrown

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina So `getView ` only works from inside a fragment and not from an activity?

Comment: Just tested it with an activity, there is no such method as `getView` in an activity ([doc link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)), and you need to keep a member variable for the xml root view, not really ideal to keep a reference to the parent element. [doc link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) for fragment which shows `getView` method

Comment: @John In case of Activity you can use findViewById(android.R.id.content)

Answer (score 19):

try this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        View view = getView();
        if(view != null) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
        }
    }
}
```

this code must works fine.
I hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

To set OnClickListeners in fragments, override `onViewCreated` in your fragment class.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    view.findViewById(R.id.yourId).setOnClickListener(this);
    //or
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourId).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

I was trying to set a timertask to automatically reload a webview in a fragment and this method was the only thing that worked for me.  My project is on [github](https://github.com/JB0x2D1/Liberty-Compass-News/tree/master/0.8.2/src/com/libcompass/androidapp).

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22175107/1744123)

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your button inside a class that extends `Fragment` it's better to do it inside the `onViewCreated()` method. This will guarantee that the view already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use the `getRootView()` method to get the data of your fragment in Activity.

```
//below block of code write in activity.

EditText et = (EditText) v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.name);
Log.d("Name", et.getText().toString());
```

name is the field of fragment.