# android : How to initialize/inflate a RelativeLayout using id defined in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set a `RelativeLayout` block in an activity to `VISIBLE`. But I can't seem to assign the `RelativeLayout` to a variable like so :

```
Relative Layout alarmSetBlock = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sleep_text_block);
```

`alarmSetBlock` is assigned `null` instead.

I think I am supposed to use something like inflater.inflate but don't know how to use it outside of fragments.

Please tell me the easiest/best way to resolve this.

layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alarm_set_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/mediumGray"
            android:text="SET ALARM"
            android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sleep_text_block"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sleep_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Alarm set to :"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alarm_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/sleep_text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout` I am trying to initialize is the second one in the layout.

Here is the fragment file for the above layout. I am trying to initialize the `RelativeLayout` inside the activity java file that holds this fragment.

```
public class SleepSetFragment extends Fragment {

    public static SleepSetFragment newInstance()
    {
        SleepSetFragment fragment = new SleepSetFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sleep_set, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the XML of your Activity?

Comment: That should work, are you using multiple layout folders? Make sure also the IDs are also set in each XML.

Comment: All my layouts are in my res/layout folder. How do I set IDs in each XML? If you mean define ID using `android:id` I've already done it here.

Comment: Can you try using android:visibility="invisible" instead, and see if it works.

Comment: I am wondering if something is wrong with my Android studio. It has been throwing this sort of "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" for a number of things.  And using the `Log.d` for this `RelativeLayout` shows that id fetch is not working properly

Comment: Funny, works fine on my end. I copied your XML and didn't return any null.

Comment: I'm using AppCompatActivity instead of Activity also

Comment: Well I have fragments in this activity so I am using `FragmentActivity`

Comment: This XML is set in the Fragment or FragmentActivity?

Comment: The xml is for a Fragment

Comment: You forgot to inflate inside onCreateView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to inflate the XML layout on onCreateView() like this

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

            RelativeLayout alarmSetBlock = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sleep_text_block);
alarmSetBlock.setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: Where do I set the visibility of my `RelativeLayout`? Should I do it in the fragment `onCreateView()` method itself along with the `SharedPreference` logic that it is connected to?

Comment: Just below the RelativeLayout alarmSetBlock line

Comment: You can review, because Fragment and Activity has different lifecycles.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a view inside a fragment from the Activity.
You can't use `findViewById()` for such cases. Instead, you should expose a public method from your fragment to use get that specific view. But make sure that your fragment is inflated and added to the activity before calling it.

Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023533/1395437

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is in a fragment file which has onCreateView()

Comment: Are you trying to get a view inside the activity from the fragment, or a view of a fragment from your activity?

Comment: Trying to get a view of a fragment inside the activity.