# How to define ListView in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, view, android-context

I'm extending in my class `AsyncTask` and I have a context passed however from another activity.
So I tried this:

```
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
```

Error:

```
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type loadSomeStuff
```

I tried this also:

```
        listview = (ListView) ctx.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
```

Error:

```
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Context
```

How can I get over this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is either `View.findViewById()` or `Activity.findViewById()`.

try

```
listview = (ListView) ((Activity)ctx).findViewById(R.id.listview1);
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aid)

Comment: @MocialoveBoris so what can i cast to a fragment??

Comment: @AndroidArabia what do you mean? You can cast a Fragment to Fragment

Comment: in your codes though you typed "Activity", i want fragment. what to do???
@MacialovBoris

Comment: listview = (ListView) ((Fragment) ctx)
      .findViewById(R.id.listview1); doesn't work

Comment: @AndroidArabia this is not your original question. Try take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013/1276374 (inflate your fragment and use findViewById on that view)

Comment: but then, how can i initialize Container (ViewGroup)??

Comment: @AndroidArabia which ViewGroup?