# How do I update ListView in another Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Activity which holds a `ViewPager` with 2 Fragments. One fragment is for adding items to `ListView` and another fragment is holding the `ListView`.

I've been trying for almost 3 days now without any positive results. How do I update the other fragment's `ListView` from the first fragment?

I'm trying to call the method that updates `ListView` from the Activity that holds `ViewPager` but it doesn't work.

Calling the method from `ViewPager` **activity** :

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    library.populateListView(getApplicationContext());
    aBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}
```

This is the `populateListView` method:

```
public void populateListView(Context context){      
    CustomListViewAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getDatabaseArrayList(context), getActivity());

        if (lView != null)
        {
            lView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

However this doesn't work because the lView variable (ListView) is null because the fragment isn't shown at the moment when this is being called.

Comment: Pass the array to the other fragment then update in that fragment when its shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that function `populateListView()` is a function of the Fragment containing the `ListView`. You are calling `populateListView()` on every call to `onPageSelected`. Should you not check what is the position that is being selected. Anyway the `populateListView()` method should be a public method of the Fragment containing `ListView`. And You Can Instantiate The Fragment from the `Viewpager` adapter in the Activity and than call this method. In That way the `listView` should not be null.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
ListViewFragment frag=(ListViewFragment)adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 1);
//here adapter is the ViewPager Adapter and you must supply the viewpager that    contains 
//the fragments and also the position of the fragment to instantiate. 
//For example 0 or 1 etc.
frag.populateListView(getApplicationContext());
aBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}
```

Comment: Yes!! I can't believe the solution was this simple all along. Thank you!

Comment: onPageSelected is for ListFragment. What about extends Fragment? Is there alternative method?

Answer (score 1):

## Understand Fragments

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290938/fragments-and-activities-where-do-i-put-my-application-logic/22291847#22291847). I have gone in great detail explaining the concept of fragments.

Pay particular attention to the definition of rootview:

```
public void onActivityCreared(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            // Do stuff on creation. This is usually where you add the bulk of your code. Like clickListners
        // You can define this object as any element in any of your xml's 
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_the_fragment_uses container,false);
        rootview.findViewById(R.id.your_id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do something 
        }
    });
}
```

In the above case I defined a button for an on click listener, but you can just as easily define a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) along with its appropriate methods.

### Alternate Solution

A second method could be using [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) or [getActivity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) (check the communicating with activity section).

For example:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.your_listView_id);

OR    (more likely solution for your problem)

View listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android) post for additional information.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

To do this safely, you have to keep your `listview` data in a higher level `Parent-Activity` not the `fragments`. Make your `MainActivity`class `singleton` class by making the constructor `private` and create a `getInstance` method that return the only initialized instance of your `MainActivity.

This will allow you to keep your data instance safe from being re-initialized or lost. Then, in `onResume` of your fragment re-set the data (get it from the `MainActivity`) to your `listview` `adapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method from the `adapter` instance.

This will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The problem is that fragment onResume doesn't execute. The onResume only executes once and then never again even when I swipe between fragments. Why is that?

Comment: Because it is cached in your `pager`. The `pager` always create the current fragment and maybe the left and the right one to allow the fast navigation.

Comment: You can control the number of preloaded fragment by `pager.setOffScreenPageLimit(1);` this will create the only current fragment

Comment: It seems like this doesn't work, I did set `pager.setOffScreenPageLimit(1)` but it still loads both fragments when app is opened

Comment: @WhizW, did you try using FragmentStatePagerAdapter? see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: This is where you can use the onPageSelected() Code. Just check if the current fragment is the one with the list (based on position) then call your update method. Since the data is stored at a higher level, you just need the UI to reflect any changes that happened