# Difference between onCreateView and onViewCreated in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

What's the essential difference between these two methods? When I create a TextView, should I use one over the other for performance?

Edit:
What's the difference from

```
onCreateView() {
  root = some view
  View v = new View(some context);
  root.add(v);
  return root;
}


onViewCreated() {
  View v = new View(some context);
  getView().add(v);
}
```

Comment: I added an edit to explain my confusion. If one method comes right after the other, why are there two? Can't all the view creation be done within a single method like as in above?

Comment: If you have to google and guess, there's probably badly named methods.

Answer (score 141):

We face some crashes initializing view in `onCreateView`.

> You should inflate your layout in `onCreateView` but shouldn't initialize other views using `findViewById` in `onCreateView`.

Because sometimes view is not properly initialized. So always use `findViewById` in `onViewCreated`(when view is fully created) and it also passes the view as parameter.

`onViewCreated` is a make sure that view is fully created.

> onViewCreated android Documentation

Called immediately after `onCreateView`(`android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup`, `android.os.Bundle`) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.

Comment: Thanks. I also faced this problem and used component.`post`(...) method to wait till it is shown. Probably will make findViewById and other initialization in `onViewCreated`.

Comment: Where was that text quoted from? I couldn't find it in the official documentation.

Comment: Can you please post the reference from Developer site of the statement quoted herewith?

Comment: This isn't actually correct. You can find a view in onCreateView, but only after you've inflated it and only from the view you inflated already. Fragment.findViewById() is not safe, but View.findViewById() is safe if you already inflated the fragment view.

Answer (score 54):

`onViewCreated` is called immediately after `onCreateView` (the method you initialize and create all your objects, including your `TextView`), so it's not a matter of performance.

From the developer site:

> onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> Called immediately after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.

Source: [Fragment#onViewCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle))

Answer (score 31):

It's better to do any assignment of subviews to fields in `onViewCreated`.  This is because the framework does an automatic null check for you to ensure that your Fragment's view hierarchy has been created and inflated (if using an XML layout file) properly.

Code snippet from: [FragmentManger.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3f453164ec884d26a556477027b430cb22a9b7e3/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#L875)

```
// This calls onCreateView()
f.mView = f.performCreateView(f.getLayoutInflater(f.mSavedFragmentState), null, f.mSavedFragmentState);

// Null check avoids possible NPEs in onViewCreated
// It's also safe to call getView() during or after onViewCreated()
if (f.mView != null) {
    f.mView.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
    if (f.mHidden) f.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    f.onViewCreated(f.mView, f.mSavedFragmentState);
}
```

Comment: it also separates any initialization logic from the view hierarchy inflation/creation logic

Comment: This is interesting, do you have any additional resources on why this approach is better? Does that mean every onCreateView method should only consist of a "return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file, container, false);" and onviewcreated should have all "findViewById" methods? What performance boost does this create? Would it make transitions faster?

Comment: To answer your first question, `onCreateView` is used to create the fragment's view hierarchy.  This can be via XML inflation or dynamic creation (i.e., creating Java views programatically).  So you may not call `inflate` at all.  But you should return some parent view if the fragment needs to have a UI element.  Otherwise return `null`.

Comment: There isn't a performance boost at all.  Looking at the `FragmentManager` and fragment code for `performCreateView`, which calls `onCreateView` https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3f453164ec884d26a556477027b430cb22a9b7e3/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L2047, you are guaranteed a few things tho for the `onViewCreated` lifecycle callback:

Comment: 1. The view hierarchy will be attached to the container if the fragment has been dynamically added to its parent activity.

2. You can safely do view lookups without worrying about NPEs.

3. I'm not that familiar with animations, but the fragment transition will have already been started (i.e., sent over to the UI thread message queue).

Answer (score 18):

`onCreateView()` is the Fragment equivalent of `onCreate()` for Activities and runs **during** the View creation.
`onViewCreated()` runs **after** the View has been created.

`should I use one over the other for performance?` **NO**. There's no evidence of a performance boost.

There is actually an `onCreate()` method in Fragments too, but it's **rarely** used (I do **never** use it, nor find a good use case for it).

I always use `onCreateView()` in Fragments as a replacement for `onCreate()`.
And I'm happy with that.

Comment: @npace, why? I also think `onCreateView` is an equivalent of Activity's `onCreate`.

Comment: @CoolMind Well, nPace is not *totally* wrong, since there's an `onCreate()` method in Framents as well. But it's **never** used (or, at least, I do **never** use it). I always use `onCreateView()` in Fragments as a replacement.

Comment: @Rotwang, agree with you! Some tutorials use onCreate to put setHasOptionsMenu(true), but I think it would better do in onCreateView or onViewCreated.

Comment: @CoolMind I do totally agree. Maybe I used the wrong words in my answer.

Comment: @Rotwang, you said right. When I used fragments first time, I also didn't know why onCreate is not used.

Comment: Normally you want to use `onCreate` to do non-view-related things like store off arguments that were passed in.  `onCreateView` should only contain logic directly related to the view.

Comment: I initialize data in onCreate() which I get using getArguments().

Comment: You should use `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`  properly. `onCreate()` will only be called once on a fragment instance, while `onCreateView()` theoretically can be called many times (theoretically, Android can delete a fragment's view if a fragment is not shown on a screen (to save memory), and then when it's shown on the screen again it calls `onCreateView()` again to re-create the view.

Answer (score 18):

[The docs for `Fragment.onCreateView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) now says:

> It is recommended to only inflate the layout in this method and move logic that operates on the returned View to onViewCreated(View, Bundle).

No need for us to understand why; we just need to do as the docs says, but it would be interesting to know why this recommendation exists. My best guess is [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), but IMHO this makes it a little bit more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: If the reason is separation of concern, then why does Activity inflate its layout in `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa Good point. The answer to that questions could simply be that it was designed by a different programmer thinking differently (fragments were introduced some years after we first got Android), but who knows.

Answer (score 14):

`onCreateView` returns the inflated view. `OnViewCreated` is called just after `onCreateView` and get has parameter the inflated view. Its return type is `void`

Comment: I added an edit to explain my confusion. If one method comes right after the other, why are there two? Can't all the view creation be done within a single method like as in above?

Comment: onCreateView should return quickly. OnViewCreate can be used to perform initialization stuff, for instance. As I said, onViewCreated has as parameter the View you inflated inside onCreateView. So you can avoid the `getView` call

Answer (score 8):

- Ok, so If we are going to talk about `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`. It is worth while to talk a little about the fragment lifecycle. The full documentation about the fragment lifecycle can be found [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle), I recommend that you read up on it, as we will only be talking about the states relevant to `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`.
- The fragment lifecycle contains 5 states:
- **1) INITIALIZED**
- **2) CREATED**
- **3) STARTED**
- **4) RESUMED**
- **5) DESTROYED**
- The reason that we need to talk about the fragment lifecycle is because both `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` get called during the `CREATED` state in the lifecycle.
- So when a fragment is instantiated, it begins in the `INITIALIZED` state, for example when you see:

```
CustomFragment frag1 = new CustomFragment() //`INITIALIZED` state
CustomFragment.class                        //`INITIALIZED` state
```

- The `.class` syntax is the `class literal` syntax and for a brief summary I would recommend reading the blog post [HERE](https://dev.to/theplebdev/java-quickie-the-class-syntax-1fib)
- For a fragment to transition into other lifecycle states, it must be added to a `Fragment Manager`.

> The Fragment Manager is responsible for determining what state its fragment should be in and then moving them into that state.

#### Difference between onCreateView() and onViewCreated()

- Once the fragment has been added to the Fragment Manager, `onAttach()` is called to attach the fragment to the host activity.
- Once `onAttch()` is called the fragment enters the `CREATED` state. It is in this state that the Android system begins creating the fragment's view. This can be done a few ways, for example the [documentation states](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created):

> In most cases, you can use the fragment constructors that take a @LayoutId, which automatically inflates the view at the appropriate time. You can also override onCreateView() to programmatically inflate or create your fragment's view

- If we look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) for `onCreateView()` we see that:

> It is recommended to only inflate the layout in this method and move logic that operates on the returned View to onViewCreated

#### Conclusion

- Now combining everything we can come to the conclusion, both `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` are called during the `CREATED` state of a fragment's life cycle. However, `onCreateView()` is called first and should only be used to inflate the fragment's view. `onViewCreated()` is called second and all logic pertaining to operations on the inflated view should be in this method.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create?authuser=0&hl=ro-RO&skip_cache=true#kotlin)

There is a new solution to declare the xml resource in the Fragment superclass

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.example_fragment) { }
```

Then bind the view in onViewCreate

```
private lateinit var binding : ExampleFragmentBinding

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = ExampleFragmentBinding.bind(view)
}
```

In this way you do not need to inflate view in onCreatedView or handle the view in onDestroy

Answer (score 2):

The main reason I would use `onViewCreated` is since it separates any initialization logic from the view hierarchy inflation/creation logic which should go in the `onCreateView` . All other performance characteristics look the same.

Answer (score 2):

i think the main different between these is when you use kotlin.in **onCreateView()** every Time you want to access to view in your xml file you should use **findViewById** but in **onViewCreated** you can simply access to your view just by calling the id of it.

Comment: Is this really true? I'm getting null for the view if I just use the id in the code either way. I need to always use the findViewById.

Comment: No it's not.. oncreate view instantiates the view, onviewcreated is called after oncreateview and before saved states are restored...  it's more a timing issue in the lifecycle of the fragment

Answer (score 1):

onCreateView is used in fragment to create layout and inflate view.
onViewCreated is used to reference the view created by above method.
Lastly it is a good practice to define action listener in onActivityCreated.