# Android: how do I access views (using findViewById) of an Activity from a Fragment onCreateView()?

Tags: android, fragment, findviewbyid

I have a pretty simple project with an Activity that contains a Fragment. Only thing you may be unfamiliar with is that I am using a [VideoEnabledWebView](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView) which isn't that complicated and is something I've used before. It's just a custom webview.

Here is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Don't forget the internet permission if you will be using the WebView to load remote content -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" > <!-- Only works in API level 11+, and allows the HTML5 videos to play in-line -->

    <activity
        android:name="name.cpr.ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**ExampleActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import cpr.name.videoenabledwebview.R;

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.i("rai", "activity onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

    }

}
```

**activity_example.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ExampleActivity">

<!-- View that will be hidden when video goes fullscreen -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment android:name="name.cpr.WebViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/webViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- View where the video will be shown when video goes fullscreen -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

**WebViewFragment.java**

```
package name.cpr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import cpr.name.videoenabledwebview.R;


public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

private VideoEnabledWebView webView;
private VideoEnabledWebChromeClient webChromeClient;
View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root, container, false);

    webView = (VideoEnabledWebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    Log.i("rai", "nonVideoLayout = " + R.id.nonVideoLayout);

    Log.i("rai", "videoLayout = " + R.id.videoLayout);

    View nonVideoLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout);

    if(nonVideoLayout == null){

        Log.i("rai", "why is nonVideoLayout null?");
    }

    ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup)     rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);

    if(videoLayout == null){

        Log.i("rai", "why is videoLayout null?");
    }

    webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

    webView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");

    return rootView;

}
}
```

**root.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="the fragment"/>

<name.cpr.VideoEnabledWebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I just can't get access to those two relative layouts in my Activity, I keep getting null.

**Things I have tried that DON'T work:**

rootView.findViewById //rootView is the return from the inflate

getActivity().findViewById

getView().findViewById

container.findViewById

I've also tried this in my fragments onCreate:

```
context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

webViewFragmentId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
        "root", "layout", context.getPackageName());

webViewId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("webView", "id",
        context.getPackageName());

nonVideoLayoutId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("nonVideoLayout", "id", context.getPackageName());
videoLayoutId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("videoLayout","id", context.getPackageName());

rootView = inflater.inflate(webViewFragmentId, null);

webView = (VideoEnabledWebView) rootView.findViewById(webViewId);

View nonVideoLayout = getActivity().findViewById(nonVideoLayoutId);
ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(videoLayoutId);

webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout);

webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

webView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");


return rootView;
```

Comment: Have you tried either casting `getActivity` like `((ExampleActivity) getActivity()).findViewById` or using that code in the `onAttach` method in the Fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update 2020-10-27

Now that `onActivityCreated` has been deprecated the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) states you should instead register a `LifecycleObserver` to know when the `Activity.onCreate()` method has completed.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62076948/1435985) for an example.

---

### Original Answer

You should override `onActivityCreated` and access the views you need from the activity in that method because when `onCreateView` is run in the fragment the activity has not yet had its layout set so you cannot access its views.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View nonVideoLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout);
    ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);
    ...
}
```

Comment: ah okay, you know what? The things I tried actually worked when I was messing with nested fragments. So I was able to access the views from an activity if the fragment was a child fragment. I guess an activity has it's layout by the time a child fragment is created? But a parent would not work. I thought I was losing my mind lol.

Comment: @Rai What do you mean by a child fragment? If you add the fragment using the `FragmentManager` that is usually done in `onCreate` of the host activity or later so in that case the view would be accessible in `onCreateView` of the fragment.

Comment: that must have been it then. I created the child fragment using a child fragment manager. So if I use a fragment manager in the onCreate of the Activity and create the fragment that way, it should work. Wow, android is so tricky :P If that works, I'll close the question and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Now that the onActivityCreated() method is deprecated , how can this be done on the latest SDK? Unable to use the fragment onViewCreated method as the activity views are not available at that point. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to override onActivityCreated() as activity view is not created until this method is called .

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View nonVideoLayout = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout);

    if(nonVideoLayout == null){

        Log.e("rai", "why is nonVideoLayout null?");
    }
    else{
        Log.e("rai", "view not null hurray");
    }
    View videoLayout =    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoLayout);

    if(videoLayout == null){

        Log.e("rai", "why is videoLayout null?");
    }else{
        Log.e("rai", "view not null hurray");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override onViewCreated. The views aren't created at the onCreate but are once the view is actually created. This post gives a little more information [Difference between onCreateView and onViewCreated in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119090/difference-between-oncreateview-and-onviewcreated-in-fragment)

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ...
}
```