# EditText inside fragment crashes app crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

The title of this question is vague because I don't really know what is happening. I hava list view inside a class called `SummerJobFragment.java` this list view has a `onItemClicked()` that is suppose to open and other fragment called `SummerJobDetailsFragment.java`. Below I've posted the code and the logcat screenshot.

SummerJobFragment.java

```
public class SummerJobsFragmnet extends Fragment {

public SummerJobsFragmnet() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Fragment getInstance() {
    Fragment fragment = new SummerJobsFragmnet();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
public void showMessage (String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    String [] places = activity.getAllPositionsNamesPhone().toArray(
            new String[activity.getAllPositionsNamesPhone().size()]);

    final ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.joblistView);
    int  prgmImages=R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    list.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(activity,places,prgmImages));
    // OnClick listner for the individual cells of the listView
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            SummerJobDetailsFragment.mMyAppsBundle.putInt("value", position);
            SummerJobDetailsFragment fragment = new SummerJobDetailsFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.displayjobs_detailed, fragment).commit();


        }
    });
}
```

SummerJobDetailsFragment.java

```
public class SummerJobDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    DataBaseHelper summerJobDB;
    public static Bundle mMyAppsBundle = new Bundle();
    public int position = SummerJobDetailsFragment.mMyAppsBundle.getInt("value");


    public SummerJobDetailsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Fragment getInstance() {
        Fragment fragment = new SummerJobsFragmnet();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.displayjobs_detailed,container,false);
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SummerJobDetailsFragment summer = new SummerJobDetailsFragment();
        DataBaseHelper summerJobDB;
        summerJobDB = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());

        Cursor res = summerJobDB.getAllData(position+1);
        EditText jobPlace = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.jobTitle);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(1));
        /*
        EditText jobPlace = (EditText)summer.getView().findViewById(R.id.jobTitle);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(1));
        EditText jobPosition = (EditText)summer.getView().findViewById(R.id.jobPlace);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(2));
        EditText starTime = (EditText)summer.getView().findViewById(R.id.jobStartingTime);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(3));
        EditText address = (EditText)summer.getView().findViewById(R.id.jobAddress);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(5));
        EditText phone = (EditText)summer.getView().findViewById(R.id.jobPhoneNum);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(6));
        EditText hours = (EditText)summer.getView().findViewById(R.id.jobHours);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(4));
        */
        return 

    }

}
```

and here is the displayjobs_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/jobplace"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobPlace"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Job Title"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Job Address:"
        android:id="@+id/jobAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Phone number:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobPhoneNum"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hours"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobHours" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Starting Time"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobStartingTime" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the logcat: 
[image: Second logcat error]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are doing the layout operations in onCreate, you should do it in onCreateView() like this :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);


EditText jobPlace = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.jobTitle);
        jobPlace.setText(res.getString(1));

...
...
}
```

Also remove this statement

```
SummerJobDetailsFragment summer = new SummerJobDetailsFragment();
```

it doesn't make any sense, you call findViewById on the rootView.

No, this is how you do it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/displayjobs_detailed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/jobplace"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobPlace"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Job Title"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Job Address:"
        android:id="@+id/jobAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Phone number:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobPhoneNum"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hours"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobHours" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Starting Time"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobStartingTime" />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your fragment use this to commit

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.displayjobs_detailed, fragment).commit();  // Note R.id instead of R.layout
```

Comment: I did what you said if put the layout inside onCreateView I get some error that I will add

Comment: Actually your code has many problems, please post the error !!

Comment: I just did post the new logcat

Comment: @dadadodo See the changes

Comment: @dadadodo Did you try? Please upvote/accept if you found my answer helpful !!

Comment: I will try it right away and let yo know. thanks for the help

Comment: I tried it. I still get the same error as I posted the second time

Comment: should we continue in chat ? There are many problems in your code !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110875/discussion-between-varunkr-and-dadadodo).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your view items in onCreateView of the Fragment not in onCreate

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    // Initialize Here
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling wrong. [Difference between onCreateView and onViewCreated in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119090/difference-between-oncreateview-and-onviewcreated-in-fragment)

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Instead of, call

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    // Initialize Here
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said i still get the same error. The second error logcat that I posted

Comment: Because there is no view as displayjobs_detailed, since you have layout named displayjobs_detail

Comment: I changed that still the same!

Comment: If you tried all as @varunkr answer. I think your question is changed a lot and the code above is little out dated. The reason no view is found is simple of course that there is no view. If you had check every things is good. I think try clean and rebuild project.

Comment: I updated the code with the new SummerJobDetailsFragment

Comment: What is your layout xml file name? Is your layout xml file name same as R.layout.displayjobs_detailed?