# When to load views in Fragment from layout in android

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I am new to android and want to know that in which lifecycle method it would be best to load views in fragment like

```
editText_full_name  = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText_full_name);
```

I am thinking of `onResume()` but something tells me its not appropriate. Nonetheless I want to know about the best practice of doing so.
Also I am using an interface as a communication callback from fragment to activity.

EDIT: Also i wanna know when to attach listeners, like onClickListeners to button in fragment lifecycle.

Comment: onCreateView method after inflation is done, or onViewCreated method;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Complete Android Fragment & Activity Lifecycle](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle).

You may want to add listener in Fragment.onViewCreated() when it's guaranteed that view hierarchy is build.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

first of all, there is a function `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState)`. There, a view initialisation can be done with the help of `LayoutInflater`. To get the reference to the child views, you have to call method `findViewById` on the view returned from `LayoutInflater` initialisation. In this function also You are provided with the `Bundle` argument, which can help you react to configuration changes (ie. screen rotating). If the `Bundle` argument is not null, then the fragment is recreated after configuration change.

Then, there is a function `public void onViewCreated(View view...)`. There, You also can init views. It is called every time, the activity opens the fragment.

As for the question regarding the performance, I sent You to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25119140/6507689)

Don't init views in `onResume` as this event is called every time the comes to foreground (sliding down and up notification panel, coming from background, screen on and off).

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is to bind views in `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)`. 
Btw, I suggest you to have a look [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).
It's a fantastic tool for binding Views. It's clear & simple, you won't need to make a lot of statements, just declare the variable as Fragment variables using `@BindView(R.id.myId)` & add `Butteknife.bind(this)` in activities, and `Butterknife.bind(this, rootView)` in fragments.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` method is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,
                container, false);

        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttin_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              //.....

              }
           });
     }
```