# How to solve "android.view.SurfaceView.getHolder()' on a null object reference"?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,View.OnClickListener {
    // Defined All Field
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Camera camera;
    private ImageView ImgThumbnail;
    private Button btnFlash, btnFrontCamera, btnCapture;
    private int cameraId;
    private boolean flashmode = false;
    private int rotation;
    private String SavedImagePath;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container,false);
        // Camera surface view created
        cameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        btnFlash = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);
        btnFrontCamera = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btnFrontCamera);
        btnCapture = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) container.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        ImgThumbnail = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.ImgThumbnail);
        btnFrontCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFlash.setOnClickListener(this);        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
            btnFrontCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (!getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            btnFlash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (!openCamera(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)) {
            alertCameraDialog();
        }
    }
    private boolean openCamera(int id) {
        boolean result = false;
        cameraId = id;
        releaseCamera();
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                setUpCamera(camera);
                camera.setErrorCallback(new Camera.ErrorCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
                    }
                });
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                result = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = false;
                releaseCamera();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void setUpCamera(Camera c) {
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);

        rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degree = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degree = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degree = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degree = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degree = 270;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            // Front Facing
            rotation = (cameraInfo.orientation + degree) % 330;
            rotation = (360 - rotation) % 360;
        } else {
            // Back Facing
            rotation = (cameraInfo.orientation - degree + 360) % 360;
        }
        c.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);
        Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
        showFlashButton(params);
        List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (focusModes != null) {            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            }
        }
        params.setRotation(rotation);
    }
    private void showFlashButton(Camera.Parameters params) {
        boolean showFlash = (getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH) && params.getFlashMode() != null)
                && params.getSupportedFlashModes() != null
                && params.getSupportedFocusModes().size() > 1;
        btnFlash.setVisibility(showFlash ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    private void releaseCamera() {
        try {
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                camera.setErrorCallback(null);
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error", e.toString());
            camera = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnFlash:
                flashOnButton();
                break;
            case R.id.btnFrontCamera:
                flipCamera();
                break;
            case R.id.btnCapture:
                takeImage();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void flashOnButton() {
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
                param.setFlashMode(!flashmode ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(param);
                flashmode = !flashmode;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Flash Touch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
    private void takeImage() {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            private File imageFile;
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                try {
                    // Convert byte array into bitmap
                    Bitmap loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    // rotate Image
                    Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                    rotateMatrix.postRotate(rotation);
                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0, loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
                    final File folder;
                    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraApp");
                    } else {
                        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraApp");
                    }
                    boolean success = true;
                    if (!folder.exists()) {
                        success = folder.mkdirs();
                    }
                    if (success) {
                        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                        imageFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString() + " " + "Image.jpg");
                        SavedImagePath = new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString() + " " + "Image.jpg";
                        imageFile.createNewFile();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Image Not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // Save image into gallery
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                    FileOutputStream file_out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    file_out.write(outputStream.toByteArray());
                    file_out.close();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());                    getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Photo Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Code For Captured Image Save in a ImageView.
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String imagePath = folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + SavedImagePath;
                            Uri myURI = Uri.parse(imagePath);
                            ImgThumbnail.setImageURI(myURI);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Photo Saved on ImageView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void flipCamera() {
        int id = (cameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK ? Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT : Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera Mode Changing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!openCamera(id)) {
            alertCameraDialog();
        }
    }
    private void alertCameraDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = createAlert(getActivity(), "Camera info", "Error to open camera");
        dialog.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
    private AlertDialog.Builder createAlert(Context context, String Title, String Message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.info_for_camera);
        if (Title != null)
            dialog.setTitle(Title);
        else
            dialog.setTitle("Information");
        dialog.setMessage(Message);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: There isn't much detail here, and questions featuring just code (with no explanation or context) tend to be closed here. What are you trying to do? Would you edit the stack trace into your question, formatted using the code tool? Have you traced the problem to a specific area of code?

Comment: My Problem was...i forget to put all myonCreateView() code into onCreatedView().

Comment: See. halfer i did as u said.
and Sorry for my faults.because i am new in Stackoverflow..

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, appreciated. Don't worry about being new, you'll pick it up easily enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you found same as my problem, then do the following. Just replace your `OnCreateView()` code into `onViewCreated()`, because `OnCreateView()` method is only useful for inflating a View.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Camera surface view created
    mCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    btnFlash = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);
    btnFrontCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFrontCamera);
    btnCapture = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    ImgThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImgThumbnail);

    btnFrontCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFlash.setOnClickListener(this);
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
        btnFrontCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (!getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
        btnFlash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: No halfer...both method are right...nothing are wrong....First method onCreateView() is usefull for only inflating a ViewGroup..and  onViewCreated() is usefull for get the parameter of inflated view().

Comment: u can find difference between both method..here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119090/difference-between-oncreateview-and-onviewcreated-in-fragment