# switching activities with textview

Tags: android

am trying to make the text under my login button "no account yet? signup now" when clicked to send me to my RegisterFragment.so i added an OnClickListener for it like this in my LoginFragment.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView signup = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginFragment.this.startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), RegisterFragment.class));

        }
    });
```

but when i run the code the app crashes on this line

```
        TextView signup = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.signup);
```

this is my fragment_login.xml file

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/signup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:text="No Account Yet? Signup_now"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

please guys i really need your help.

Comment: Inflate you xml file where you have declared the textview before initialising the textview

Answer (score 2):

onCreateView() method is responsible for creating view, so you should first create it.
You can't directly use `getView()` inside `onCreateView()`.

You need to inflate it first like

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
```

Then use

```
TextView signup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.signup);
```

So full code should look like this

```
@Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
                TextView signup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.signup);
                signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                    }
                });

    return view;
}
```

On side note, setting up click listener initializing TextView's etc should be done inside `onViewCreated()`. `onCreateView()` should just create & return the view.

like

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
TextView signup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.signup);
// and so on...
}
```

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with using onCreateView to set listeners

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, there's nothing wrong in it, but doing it in proper way won't harm even. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861425/1852343

Comment: thanks alot it worked but when i click on the link it shows unfortunately app has stoped.logcat points to this line                 " startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), RegisterFragment.class));"

Comment: Is your RegisterFragment class a Fragment or Activity?

Comment: @Eric Read the logcat for `Caused by`. "Unforuntely app has stopped" is not any reasonable error message.

Comment: @sam_0829 Hmm. Didn't know about the null check. Is the page blank when the View is null?

Comment: @Eric You can't `start` an **Activity** for a Fragment class.

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you suggest i do?

Comment: @Eric as cricket_007 said, you can't start a Fragment like this. This is separate question so accept this answer if it has helped & try to find How to replace fragment. This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39825000/1852343
If you struggle in this, then please post separate question

Comment: @sam_0829 Might want to edit the answer to remove `startActivity`, then

Comment: please how can i start a fragment? i appreciate you guys help so far you guys are great

Comment: @Eric it seems you are still having problem with this one. Is it so?

Comment: @sam_0829 i have finally resolved it, thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend not setting a click listener into something you want to type into
2. You can't call `getView` before `onCreateView` has actually returned a proper `View`

[findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment#6496000)

3. `RegisterFragment.class` is not an Activity, you cannot `startActivity` for it.

Use the FragmentManager

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.<someContainer>, RegisterFragment.class)
    .commit();
```

Or you can see the documentation on [Communication between Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to see how you might implement on `onLogin()` or `onRegistrationSelected()` action to swap out to the registration fragment or "post-login" main fragment.