# Is there any method after creating the view of fragments?How to change Layout of tabs after creating fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to call a method in which I parse the JSON objects and set the values I sets values in  TextFields and button values, I created fragments but after creating the fragments how will I change the text field values

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        //Switch to different layout accordingly
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receipt, container, false);
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_totals, container, false);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keyboard, container, false);
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keylock, container, false);
                break;
            }

        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I tried to call the method in `onStart` but onStart method is been called first before the `onCreateView` and hence I get null pointer exception when I am assigning the value :

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    parseJsonResponse(response_message);
  }
```

In the parseJsonResponse() method, I sets the value

```
String UIFooter = ResponseHeaderObject.getString("FOOTER");
//Set Header Display
headerTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);
headerTextView.setText(UIHeader);
```

here is the error from logcat:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.mpos.kits.smartpos.PosMainActivity.parseJsonResponse(PosMainActivity.java:366)
```

Comment: There is literally a method called `onViewCreated` in a fragment. Had you only googled the title of your question, you would've found it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between onCreateView and onViewCreated in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119090/difference-between-oncreateview-and-onviewcreated-in-fragment)

Answer (score 2):

Fragments have a function named: `onViewCreated` which called after your view was created

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that method exists: `onViewCreated`. however, if you want to assign a text to the `TextView` outside the method on which it has been created, you have to declare the `TextView` as a member property (outside any method), to allow its use by all class methods. Otherwise, within a fragment, it will be difficult to manipulate it.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.mpos.kits.smartpos.PosMainActivity.parseJsonResponse(PosMainActivity.java:366)

You are getting this error because this `headerTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);` returns `null` in your fragment unless it's referred to a root view like in the `onCreateView` method. this way `(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);`

If you want to override `onViewCreated` method, do it this way:

```java
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //your code
    }
```

Comment: i tried using    @Override
    public View onViewCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        parseJsonResponse(response_message);
    }
but this complaints method doesnot overide superclass method 
Can you show me an example for to call this onViewCreated() method

Comment: I edited the answer to add the `onViewCreated` method

Comment: Ok I did that but now my method can not be called 
@Override
        public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
             parseJsonResponse(response_message);
        }
It gives me error non static field cannot be referenced from a static context android
parseJsonResponse() is in my Activity class and I cannot change that to 
   static method 
 public  void parseJsonResponse(String jsonResponse){// Parse the response and the textview and button  values i change according to parsed values}

Comment: @JerryAbraham, can you please declare your variables before the `onCreateView` method? as I stated in the answer

Comment: yes I did that , now my problem is that When I move from one tab to another parseJsonResponse()  gets called ,
I want to update all the layout of the tabs regardless in which tab Iam , Is this possible?I have got 3 to 4 tabs with different layouts I want to update all the tabs regardless which tab is displayed .Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927163/how-to-update-layout-all-layouts-in-different-tabs-in-tabs-in-android-tabs-wit

Comment: Let me take a look but you didn't mention that the first problem or the question itself has been answered