# Give a certain EditText focus

Tags: android

I'm using 2 EditText next to each other, the left one gains focus on the fragment startup, I want to give the right one focus I've tried to call requestFocus() on the right EditText but it's not working

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sandwich_fragment,container, false);

        sandwichNameEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.sandwich_name_edit_text);
        sandwichPriceEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.sandwich_price_edit_text);
        insertSandwichImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.insert_sandwich_btn);
        sandwichListView = view.findViewById(R.id.sandwich_list);

        dbHandler = new DBHandler(getContext(),null);
        sandwichArrayList = dbHandler.getSandwiches();

        final SandwichListAdapter adpater = new SandwichListAdapter(getContext(),
                R.layout.sandwich_item, sandwichArrayList);

            sandwichListView.setAdapter(adpater);


        insertSandwichImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(sandwichNameEditText.getText().toString().equals("") || sandwichPriceEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No empty strings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Sandwich sandwich = new Sandwich(sandwichNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                        Double.parseDouble(sandwichPriceEditText.getText().toString()));
                dbHandler.addSandwich(sandwich);
                adpater.add(sandwich);
                sandwichNameEditText.setText("");
                sandwichPriceEditText.setText("");
                sandwichNameEditText.requestFocus(); // working here

            }
        });
        sandwichNameEditText.requestFocus(); // not working here
        return view;
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please add some code snippets.

Comment: sorry, but I thought the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `requestFocus` in the `onViewCreated` method.

The request for focus is something you should do once your `View` is created.

You can find some insights about the difference between `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` methods for a `Fragment` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119090/difference-between-oncreateview-and-onviewcreated-in-fragment).

That said, you should move your view elements initialisations in the `onViewCreated` as well, since they're something you want to do *after* the view is created and not *while* it's being created. Just leave the `inflate` logic there, and do the other logic once the `View` is there.

Comment: Glad to have helped, happy coding!