# findViewByID() is not working. What should I do?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-alertdialog, findviewbyid

Here is my code:

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Clear cache memory");
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete cache memory ?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
      {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
            {
                //context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
                //context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
                // TODO: Implement this method
                WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView1);
                browser.clearHistory();
                browser.clearFormData();
                browser.clearCache(true);
            }


        });
```

Comment: In which layout is the `mainWebView1` supposed to be in? What does "not working" actually mean?

Comment: Please try being more specific: dosn't compile, some error is displayed, etc.

Comment: Post your log cat output

Comment: You need to call getView() first. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android

Comment: use getView().findviewbyId()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use getView(). This will return the root view for the fragment, with this you can call findViewById().

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Clear cache memory");
builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete cache memory ?");
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
        {
            //context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
            //context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
            // TODO: Implement this method
            WebView browser = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mainWebView1);
            browser.clearHistory();
            browser.clearFormData();
            browser.clearCache(true);
        }


    });
```