# Android app NPE: Unable to invoke virtual method setOnClickListener on null object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm building my first Android app (basic calculator) which consists of one Activity and a single fragment. The layout of the app (display and buttons) are defined in the fragment xml `fragment_main.xml` and should be inflated on startup. However, the app immediately crashed with a NPE. I'm confused as to whether I should set the click listeners for the calculator buttons in the Activity's `onCreate()` method, or in the fragment class's `onCreateView()` method. Code and stack trace below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.github.idclark.calculator/com.github.idclark.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView mCalculatorDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new CalculatorFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        mCalculatorDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        findViewById(R.id.AC).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.plusminus).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.percent).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.nine).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.eight).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.seven).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.six).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.five).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.four).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.three).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.two).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.one).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.zero).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.div).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.mult).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.plus).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.minus).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.dec).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.equal).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String buttonPressed = ((Button )v).getText().toString();
        mCalculatorDisplay.setText(buttonPressed);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment {

        public CalculatorFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_Main

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Fragment_Main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="65dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/AC"
        android:id="@+id/AC"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/plusminus"
        android:id="@+id/plusminus"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/percent"
        android:id="@+id/percent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/div"
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/nine"
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/eight"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/seven"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/mult"
        android:text="@string/mult"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/six"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/five"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/four"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/minus"
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/three"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/two"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:id="@+id/zero" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/dec"
        android:id="@+id/dec"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/equal"
        android:id="@+id/equal"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It should be in fragment's onCreateView.

Comment: one of those views is null. Make sure they're all in the layout or post the xml for us to see.

Comment: @jvrodrigues i've updated the question with the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the Null Pointer Exception is that the differents views (`Button`s and `TextView`) you are trying to access are not in your activity's layout file, but in your Fragment's layout file.

[setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) adds all the views in the layout file to the activity.

To fix the NPE, you need to instantiate the views (`Button`s and `TextView`) in your fragment's `onCreateView`, because the fragment's layout file contains all the views you are going to use.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new CalculatorFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


     /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
    public static class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment  implements OnClickListener {

        private TextView mCalculatorDisplay;

        public CalculatorFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


            mCalculatorDisplay = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            rootView.findViewById(R.id.AC).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.plusminus).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.percent).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.nine).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.eight).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.seven).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.six).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.five).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.four).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.three).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.two).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.one).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.zero).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.div).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.mult).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.minus).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.dec).setOnClickListener(this);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.equal).setOnClickListener(this);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String buttonPressed = ((Button )v).getText().toString();
            mCalculatorDisplay.setText(buttonPressed);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: With this I get an empty (all grey no text) screen, but the app doesn't throw an NPE. Do I need to instantiate each button individually? when i try to call `setContentView` from the fragment class, it give a compile error `non-static method cannot be called from static context`

Comment: What do you mean by `all grey no text`? Do the buttons show? Unless you want to use the button, you already instantiated it and set an `onClickListener` to it. For fragments, you only need to inflate the layout, not `setContentView`.

Comment: I meant neither the `TextView` or `Button`s appeared. I fixed it by updating the class name to `tools:context=".MainActivity$CalculatorFragment"` in the fragment layout xml.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `Fragment`'s `onViewCreated()` because it is guaranteed that all `View`s are instantiated.

Create a field in your `CalculatorFragment` to store the `OnClickListener` to be assigned to your buttons, you can do it like the following:

```
public static class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment {
    OnClickListener mListener = null;
    public CalculatorFragment(OnClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    //et cetera
```

In the Activity's `onCreate()` you must specify the `OnClickListener` when creating the `CalculatorFragment`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new CalculatorFragment(this))
            .commit();
}
```

In the overriden `onViewCreated()`, use `getView()` to get the `View` returned by `onCreateView()` so most calls become like
`getView().findViewById(R.id.the_id).setOnClickListener(this);`
.

See [findViewById in fragment android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android) to see how you can use findViewById