# Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I am trying to implement a button into a fragment in order to use the soundPool in order to play a sound with a button. At the moment the playSound1 is coming up as never used and I have tried to implement the onClick Method but it is now coming up saying it cannot resolve the method. How do I link the soundPool to a button in a fragment? this is the .java file

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
        clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1, 1);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);

        Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            }

            public void playSound1()
            {Clubb1.play(clubb1Id,1,1,1,0,1);}
        });
```

Comment: Place your return at then end of `OnCreateView()`

Comment: Related to [findViewById in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to :

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
        clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1, 1);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);

        Button buttonA = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Clubb1.play(clubb1Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            }

        });

        return veiw;
    }
```

You did a lot of mistakes here. So im not sure that my approach help you enough )  Write your program result into comment and we`ll try more.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple mistakes in your code.

1. You return a value way to early, the code beyond your return statement isn't executed
2. You're inflating the View, but all your inner elements eg your button is in that  view so you have to find that view by id in that view.

I corrected it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
        Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
        clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1, 1);

        Button buttonA = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            }

            public void playSound1()
            {Clubb1.play(clubb1Id,1,1,1,0,1);}
        });

       return root;
}
```