# FindViewById in MvxFragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, mvvmcross

I need to find a view I declared in axml in a MvxFragment. In an Activity I can call `FindViewById<T>(RESOURCE_ID)` in `OnCreate`. This doesn't work in fragments.

This is how it works with normal Android fragments: [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment-android)

How do I inflate a view in a `MvxFragment` without losing the binding context?

Answer (score 7):

This is how it works:

You need to know about the two extension methods `EnsureBindingContextIsSet()` and `BindingInflate()`.

```
public class MyFragment : MvxFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.EnsureBindingContextIsSet(savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.YOUR_VIEW, container, false);
        var searchField = view.FindViewById<T>(Resource.Id.RESOURCE_ID);


        return view;
    }
}
```