# How can I change a Fragment text?

Tags: java, android

This is my `Fragment` class and I have a textView in xmlfile

How can I change the `TextView` by setText?

```
public class Frist extends Fragment   {

    TextView text;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frist, container, false);
        TextView t = (TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText("SOME TEXT");

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [findViewById in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
TextView t = (TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

You should be calling `findViewById` on the view you inflate:

```
TextView t = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```