# error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Tags: android

**this is the fragmentOne.java**
    package piestudio.opinion;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * Created by jene on 7/4/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){

            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem Item){
              int id = Item.getItemId();

            if( id  == R.id.toi) {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                FragmentOne FragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
                FragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.content_frame,FragmentOne,"Times of India")
                        .commit();
                drawer.closeDrawer(navigationView);
            }
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i am getting these errors

**Error:(19, 64) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(27, 54) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:(29, 32) error: non-static method beginTransaction() cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(37, 54) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)**

Comment: As this class is fragment you dont have layout resource in your onCreate method. layout created after your onCreateView where you are creating view. Below is fragment life cycle.https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Answer (score 4):

Fragment haven't method

> findViewById

You need `getView()` and use that method. Check this [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment)

So change the line to:

```
final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Plus in fragments work with view should be in/after onCreateView method of fragment life-cycle after inflating fragment's layout.

Comment: `getView()` can be `null` in `onCreateView()`. In this case use `view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);` (where `view = inflater.inflate(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    View content = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change below line one by one

**Step 1 :**

```
 final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

to this

```
 final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

**Step 2** :

```
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

to this

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

**Step 3 :**

Change this

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

to this

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Use [getView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29). This will return the root view for the fragment, with this you can call `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.visited_task, null);

 final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) root.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

return root;
```