# Android: findViewById return type is View instead of ScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml, uiscrollview

I'm trying to figure out why my call to findViewById on my layout is returning the generic type "View" instead of the type "ScrollView" that the view in question is declared as.

If you look below, my xml file clearly lists the view with id "scrollview" as a `<ScrollView>`, yet findViewById on this element only returns a View, not a ScrollView. Why is this happening?

Note: the parent container to this xml layout is a Fragment, not sure if this changes things.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_capo, container, false);

    mScrollview = v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);                 //ERROR HERE
    mScrollview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //mScrollview.smoothScrollTo();
            return true;                                                   //true = not scrollable
        }
    });
}
```

**scroller_layout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLayoutParent"
            android:orientation="vertical"  >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById` return a `View`. You need to `cast` it to a `ScrollView` as follows,

```
mScrollview = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change  `mScrollview = v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);` to

```
 mScrollview = (ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
```

FindViewById returns `View` which is super class of all ui elements therefore u need to cast it to specific type.

Answer (score 1):

please cast

```
 mScrollview = (ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
```

Answer (score -1):

Always in the case of fragment you need to cast your layout or widgets to view for eg:mscroll=(Scrollview)yourview.findviewbyid(R.id.scroll) and I also ask you to take a look at this.  [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment)