# Create listview in a tab fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I tried to create a tab that can show the listview in it.. After i create evrything the red line appear at 3 part (as below) show at the problem.. I tried everything still not working..I hope someone can give me hint or some helpful answer..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Alhaadi on 23/3/2017.
 */

public class Drink extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ListView list;
    String[] itemname ={
            "Safari",
            "Camera",
            "Global",
            "FireFox",
            "UC Browser",
            "Android Folder",
            "VLC Player",
            "Cold War",
            "Nasi Basi",
    };

    String[] price = {
            "rm 9.00",
            "rm 7.00",
            "rm 8.00",
            "rm 5.00",
            "rm 9.00",
            "rm 15.00",
            "rm 8.00",
            "rm 8.00",
            "rm 9.00",
    };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.food1,
            R.drawable.food2,
            R.drawable.food3,
            R.drawable.food4,
            R.drawable.food5,
            R.drawable.food6,
            R.drawable.food7,
            R.drawable.food8,
            R.drawable.food9,
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drink, container, false);
        return rootView;

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname,    imgid, price);//here the problem
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainlistdrink); //here the problem redline at findviewbyId
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //here the problem redline at getaApplicationContext()
            }
        });
    }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] itemname;
        private final Integer[] imgid;
        private final String[] price;


        public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid, String[] price) {
            super(context, R.layout.drinklist, itemname);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.context=context;
            this.itemname=itemname;
            this.imgid=imgid;
            this.price=price;
        }

        public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.drinklist, null,true);

            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.drinkname);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.drinklistview);
            TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.drinkname);

            txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
            extratxt.setText(price[position]);
            return rowView;

        }
    }

}
```

This is the Tab class..

```
package com.example.alhaadi.foodvault;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tabmenu extends AppCompatActivity{

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabmenu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Food food  = new Food();
                return food;

            case 1:
                Drink drink = new Drink();
                return drink;

            case 2:
                Bread bread = new Bread();
                return bread;

            case 3:
                Dessert dessert = new Dessert();
                return dessert;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "FOOD";
            case 1:
                return "DRINK";
            case 2:
                return "BREAD";
            case 3:
                return "DESSERT";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Your `Adapter` needs a `Context`, and `this` - the `Fragment` - is not a `Context`. Use `getActivity()` instead of `this`, as an `Activity` is a `Context`. 2) Fragment doesn't have a `findViewById()` method. You need to [find your `View`s in the `rootView` you just inflated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013) - `rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainlistdrink)`. 3) `Fragment` does not have a `getApplicationContext()` method. Again, you need a `Context` there, so use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. 4) Lastly, the `return rootView;` line must be at the end of `onCreateView()`.

Comment: oohhh...sir..thank you so much..I spend two day to figure what happen...u just save my day.. God bless u sir..ty..its working now..Thumb up

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to change your Integer[] to int[], maybe i guess