# Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' in Fragment of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hello, I have a Fragment for a ViewPager:

```
package my.test.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private Button btn;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // point A
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
    }
}
```

When I would add this under point A, it comes a error message:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // point A
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
}
```

The error message:

```
Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'
```

What can I do?

Comment: in fragment it is a inflated layout hence it can be found through inflated view so use view.findViewById() where view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);

Comment: Don't use Fragment if you are beginner (I assume that you are).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013

Comment: When you get 7 answers in as many minutes, it's a sure sign that you didn't do enough research on your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access any view, you have view object to access it.

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
         btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

       return view;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in `OnViewCreated()` method:

```
btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if want to bind your controls in `fragment` than your have to first get the  your layout in to a `view` using `LayoutInflater` than with the help of that `view` you can bind your all controls like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
        btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        return rootView  ;
    }
```

Comment: I had saved you c:

Comment: and may know the reason for down votes

Comment: The only problem that I see is a missed "="

Comment: TBH all answers here are wrong, because everyone should use ButterKnife.

Comment: @PavelSavchkov. Using ButterKnife is something that a developer might prefer, but that doesn't make other answers wrong

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE C'mon, that's just kind of joke. On the other hand, I really recommend ButterKnife for everyone. It makes the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: @PavelSavchkov. I'm fine with that, but there are users around here, like OP, that have no clue about what they're doing and they might not see your comment as a joke. They might really think that the other answers are wrong although they are clearly not

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Tbh, I just don't realize why the people can't just use google for a such simple problem. It's just like: "Oh, ok let just someone else solve the problem". I think that it's not how anyone should learn programming or even whatever.

Comment: @PavelSavchkov. I agree with you on that. Especially questions like these.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
 view.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
  btn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
  return  rootView ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Fragment` is not a subclass of `Activity`.

You have to call `findViewById(R.id.*id*);` on a `Activity` object.

See [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).