# Access a Database fromout a Fragment to DIsplay in List

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-fragments

Ok so i tried to learn of all These other questions here, but i am not getting the hang of it, so i decided to ask by myself.
I got a Main Activity with different Fragments for changing the views (used the Android Standard sidebar activity template). From there the user creates Tasks via a separate Acitivty which Returns the values. In the Main Activity the Tasks are getting stored into the SQLite-database. So far it works.

Now i have the Fragment TaskList with the corresponding layout TaskList_main.xml. In this XML file i got a simple ListView which i want to fill with the values from the database. My Problem is where to write that method and when to Access it. the method would be

```
public void showAllListEntries() {

    List<TaskData> TaskList = datasource.getAllTasks();
    //Daten werden im ArrayAdapter gespeichert
    ArrayAdapter<TaskData> TaskListArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TaskList);

    ListView TaskDataListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TaskListView);
    TaskDataListView.setAdapter(TaskListArrayAdapter);
}
```

My Fragment is empty like this atm

```
public class TaskList extends Fragment {
View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_tasklist, container, false);

    return view;
}
}
```

I can also send the main Activity if you like but it's a bit messy

So can someone tell me how i get this to work? And did i explain my Problem clearly?

Comment: My Android is a bit rusty, but if I understand you correctly, the most logical place to put the `showAllListEntries()` method would be in the `TaskList` fragment...

Comment: then id have to create my datasource there, so far no prob, but i cant get a reference to my listview from the Fragment, cuz the Fragment doesn't know the "findViewById" method

Comment: You can get the reference to the `ListView` in `onViewCreated` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment . For the datasource - you could either pass its reference to the `Fragment` from your `Activity` or use a singleton.

Comment: Now what's a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `onCreateView`. But you should make an [async](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) call to get the tasks to display and have your fragment as a listener. When you get the tasks you can create your adapter and attach it to the `ListView`.

And you should have a ProgressBar in `TaskList_main.xml` (which should be renamed to `task_list_fragment.xml`, I don't think there is a naming convention for layouts, but this is quite used) and hide it when you receive the data.

Comment: What is a loader? How to integrate that? And what do you mean by async calls and Fragment as listener? Sorry for that many questions

Comment: @einsiedler sorry, by loader I mean a ProgressBar. I'll edit the answer. And I'll add a link for the async part