# ListView Adapters in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter

I have this code...

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final RelationShipAdapter adapter = null;
        lvRelationShipAllUser.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                int test = i;
                connectOrDisconnectUser(test);
            }
        });

        lvRelationShipAllUser = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvRelationShip);
        lvRelationShipAllUser.setAdapter(adapter);
        //context = BlankFragment.this;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.relationship, container, false);
    }
```

The error says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

On this line:

```
lvRelationShipAllUser.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
```

Whats the issue....?

When it's in this own class (No Fragments) there is no issue.

Comment: Please show how you have initialized lvRelationShipAllUser.

Comment: final RelationShipAdapter adapter = null;  , where do you create the adapter?

Comment: You're trying to call `setOnItemClickListener()` on `lvRelationShipAllUser` before you even find it, and you're not doing that correctly for a `Fragment`. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013.

Comment: private ListView lvRelationShipAllUser;

Comment: you need initialize the adapter:   
final RelationShipAdapter adapter = new RelationShipAdapter .. ;

Comment: @MikeM. Can you help me out, be more specific. What should I do?

Comment: Follow the example in that answer: `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relationship, ...);`, `lvRelationShipAllUser = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvRelationShip);`, then the other lines, then change the return to `return v;`.

Comment: can you answer with the exact code I would use? I am a noob.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/M9WDsq6N