# Cannot use value from edittext in android fragment, where to place it?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I know it's probably very simple, but my app is not working. I need to input weight in `Edittext` and use its value, and the total distance value from the method `CalculateDistance` and the value of the `CalculateCalories` method. 
With this code, I'm not able to click on `Start` Button. 
Where do I have to add code which gets the value from `Edittext` and how can I make it work?

My code currently looks like this:

```java
public class RunningModeFragment extends Fragment implements IGPSActivity
{

    MyLocation myLocation=null;
    Button btnRunningModeStart=null;
    EditText txtWeight=null;
    TextView txtTotalDistance=null;
    TextView txtCalories=null;
    Button btnShowRunningHistory = null;

    String weight;
    Float weightInKg;
    Float caloriesBurned;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.running_mode_fragment, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        txtTotalDistance=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtTotalDistance);
        txtWeight=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
        txtCalories=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtCalories);
        if (txtWeight.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            return;
        }
        else {
            weight = txtWeight.getText().toString();
            weightInKg = Float.parseFloat(weight);
        }

        btnRunningModeStart = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnRunningModeStart);
        btnRunningModeStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onClick_StartRunningMode(v);
            }
        });

        btnShowRunningHistory = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnShowRunningHistory);
        btnShowRunningHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick_ShowRunningHistory(v);
            }
        });

    }

    private void onClick_ShowRunningHistory(View v) {

        Fragment fragment = new RunningHistoryFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "Running History");
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.commit();
    }


    private void onClick_StartRunningMode(View v)

    {
        if(myLocation ==null)
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    DatabaseFacade dbfacade = new DatabaseFacade(getView().getContext());
                    Activity activity = new Activity(ActivityMode.RUNNING);
                    activity.setActivityId(activity.getActivityId());
                    activity.setStart(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
                    dbfacade.saveActivity(activity);

                }
            }).start();


            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Start Running mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myLocation = new MyLocation();
            myLocation.LocationStart(this);
            btnRunningModeStart.setText("Stop");
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Stop Running mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myLocation.LocationListenerStop();
            myLocation = null;
            btnRunningModeStart.setText("Start");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    Location lastPoint = null;
    float totalDistance = 0;

    public static float CalculateDistance(Location startPoint, Location endPoint)
    {
        return (startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint) / ((float)1000));
    }

    public static float CalculateCalories(float a, float b){
        return ((float)1.036)*a*b;
    }



    @Override
    public void locationChanged(Location location)
    {
        try
        {

            if(lastPoint==null)lastPoint = location;

            totalDistance += CalculateDistance(lastPoint, location);

            lastPoint=location;
            txtTotalDistance.setText(totalDistance + " km");
            caloriesBurned=CalculateCalories(totalDistance,weightInKg);
            txtCalories.setText(caloriesBurned + " kcal");

            DatabaseFacade dbf = new DatabaseFacade(getView().getContext());
            Activity activity = new Activity(ActivityMode.RUNNING);
            dbf.saveLocation(new GpsLocation(activity.getActivityId(), location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getAccuracy()));
        }catch (Exception E)

        {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        ((Main) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Running mode");
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((Main) getActivity());
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.runningMode);

    }
}
```

I need to do the following:
get the value from EditText txtWeight, parse it to float and use in CalculateCalories method

```
  public static float CalculateCalories(float a, float b){
        return ((float)1.036)*a*b;
    }
```

I tried with this, but it's not working

```
  if (txtWeight.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }
    else {
        weight = txtWeight.getText().toString();
        weightInKg = Float.parseFloat(weight);
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get, when you click on the start button? And which line in your code does the stacktrace point to?

Comment: it doesn't show me any errors, without this couple lines (weight, weightinkg,calculate calories)  program works fine,clicking on button is possible, it show me messages and calculates distance, but when I add these lines, I can't do anything

Comment: Instead of using getView() use view in your onViewCreated()

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a view than initialize textview inside onCreateView like this,

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_unapproved_leave, container, false);
Textview tv= view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

the code your have written in onViewCreated() should be in onCreateVIew(). remove it from onViewCreated().

Answer (score 0):

You can put it on your `onCreateView()` as @jitendra purohit told to you, as follows :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_unapproved_leave, container, false);
        txtTotalDistance=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalDistance);
        txtWeight=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
        txtCalories=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCalories);
        ...
        return view;
    }
```

Or you can keep your code in your `onViewCreated()` but instead of `getView()` you can do `getActivity()` something like this :

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        txtTotalDistance=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtTotalDistance);
        txtWeight=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
        txtCalories=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtCalories);
        ...
```

See this [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment) aswell...

You can do that in an `onClick()` or if you do want to show the changes dynamically use `TextWatcher`.

1. Using `TextWatchers`

   TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (txtWeight.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
               return;
           }
           else {
               weight = txtWeight.getText().toString();
               weightInKg = Float.parseFloat(weight);
               //Call your CalculateCalories method
           }
       }
   };
   ```

   }
2. Using `onClick` I'm not going to implement it, but you can do it with a `Button` or on the same `EditText` and do the same stuff that in `afterChangedText()` on `TextWatcher`.

Remember in `onCreateView()` you'll have to do this :

```
txtWeight.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: thank youu!!
what about this part where I'm getting the value and using float.parse, do I have to move it somewhere else?

Comment: @Janeeee edit the question and put only that code, your code is big.

Comment: @Janeeee Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Put that line ==> weight = txtWeight.getText().toString(); in the onCLick method

```
btnShowRunningHistory = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnShowRunningHistory);
    btnShowRunningHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (txtWeight.getText().toString().isEmpty())
              {
                  return;
              }
         else {
                  weight = txtWeight.getText().toString();
                  weightInKg = Float.parseFloat(weight);
              }
            onClick_ShowRunningHistory(v);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*If you are using View binding*

Add this line under onViewCreated

val binding=<BindingFile>.bind(<binding.root from onCreate View>)
and try accessing values now using local binding variable.


 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentSigninBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        val udata = "don't have a account ?"
        val content = SpannableString(udata)
        content.setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), 0, udata.length, 0)
        binding.textView5.text = content
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val root = FragmentSigninBinding.bind(binding.root)
//        Navigate to signup fragment
        binding.signup.setOnClickListener {
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_signin_to_signup)

        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).