# RecyclerView : Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem when I try to test my app, I'm a begginer in Android Studio and tried to put a reyclerview in a fragment but when I compile I get this message :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the file that is the cause :

```
package e.user.popcorn;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigation;
private FrameLayout mMainFrame;

private HomeFragment homeFragment;
private MoviesFragment moviesFragment;
private UsersFragment usersFragment;
private ChatFragment chatFragment;
private SweetsFragment sweetsFragment;

List<Movie_data> bo_movies;

TextView mTopBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

    mMainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    mBottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);


    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
    usersFragment = new UsersFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
    sweetsFragment = new SweetsFragment();

    bo_movies = new ArrayList<>();
    bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
    bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
    bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
    bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
    bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));

    RecyclerView myRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id);
    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,bo_movies);
    myRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    myRv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    setFragment(homeFragment);
    mTopBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_bar_title);
    mTopBar.setText(R.string.nav_item_home);

    mBottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_home :
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    mTopBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_bar_title);
                    mTopBar.setText(R.string.nav_item_home);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_movies :
                    setFragment(moviesFragment);
                    mTopBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_bar_title);
                    mTopBar.setText(R.string.nav_item_movies);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_users :
                    setFragment(usersFragment);
                    mTopBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_bar_title);
                    mTopBar.setText(R.string.nav_item_users);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_chat :
                    setFragment(chatFragment);
                    mTopBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_bar_title);
                    mTopBar.setText(R.string.nav_item_chat);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_sweets :
                    setFragment(sweetsFragment);
                    mTopBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_bar_title);
                    mTopBar.setText(R.string.nav_item_sweets);
                    return true;

                default :
                    return false;

            }


        }

    });

}


private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
}
```

Here is the fragment_home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorMainBackgroundDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_latest_trailers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_latest_trailers"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/video_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_latest_trailers"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_box_office"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_latest_trailers"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_frame"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_box_office">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Toolbar mTopBar;

    List<Movie_data> bo_movies;

    public HomeFragment() {


        bo_movies = new ArrayList<>();
        bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
        bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
        bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
        bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));
        bo_movies.add(new Movie_data("Avengers", "Action", "Description de ouf", R.drawable.test));



        // Required empty public constructor

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        RecyclerView myRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id);
        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,bo_movies);
        myRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
        myRv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

}
```

I tried changing the layoutmanager but can't find the solution at the moment ...

If you need more informations just ask me and I'll provide all you need.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Share your respective XML code

Comment: RecyclerView myRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id); does the error send you to this line

Comment: Problem in your code is " RecyclerView myRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id);"  in this line. either you are using wrong id or you are binding Recyclerview at wrong place.I think you have recyclerview in your fragment xml.

Comment: Yes i do have a RecyclerView in the Fragment, is it not compatible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting a `NPE` because the `RecyclerView` is in the layout of the `Fragment`, but the code is looking for it in the layout of the `Activity`.

This line

```
RecyclerView myRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id);
```

Is looking for a `View` with the id `recyclerView_id` in the layout `activity_main` that is set here

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

If you want to put the `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment`, you will need to put the `RecyclerView` code inside the `Fragment` class. So following lines would go in the `Fragment` class

```
RecyclerView myRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id);
RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,bo_movies);
myRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
myRv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

And in the `Fragment` you would set `fragment_home` as your layout

```
public View onCreateView(...) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly i cannot put the findViewById in the home fragment :/

Comment: Your welcome. You can, but you need a reference to a `View`. Then you call view.findViewById .. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013/7395923).