# Cannot resolve symbol 'Button' when trying to send user to external link

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener, findviewbyid

newbie here to android/java code... fully expect downvotes. but hopefully some other dude will be able to easily find this and not have to ask what the problem is.

Trying to get a button when clicked to send user to an external website

```
public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {

public MessagesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent viewIntent =
                    new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);

}

}
```

Button,(Button)findViewById, setOnClickListener, OnClickListener(), Intent, Intent, Uri. all have errors -_-

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#67ffae"
tools:context=".MessagesFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Messages Fragment" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalala I know its mostly code that's what we are discussing stack overflow.

Comment: Do you have `import` statements at the top of the class for `android.widget.Button`, `android.content.Intent`, `android.net.Uri`, etc.?

Comment: yes I now do the only error now is with findViewById

Comment: and onclicklistener

Comment: `OnClickListener` is another `import`: `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`. Hit ctrl+alt+O, I think it is, and it should do those semi-automatically. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013) to see how to use `findViewById()` in a `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: im not sure how the findViewById() relates to mine. thanks for the help!

Comment: `Fragment` does not have a `findViewById()` method. You have to `inflate()` the `View` first, and call `findViewById()` on that, like is shown in that answer.

Comment: getView(). crashes the app and onCreateView() will not run

Comment: You're looking at the wrong one. Follow the answer I linked directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013.

Comment: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent viewIntent =
                        new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);

Comment: Yes, sorry I had not seen you updated message. now button does nothing, no errors though

Comment: Note the `return` statement there: `return view;`.

Comment: unexpected return value

Comment: You need to change your `return inflater.inflate(...);` statement to that. Don't try to add that somewhere else.

Comment: wouldn't that break the navigation view I have setup though?

Comment: no it doesn't thank you for your help!

Comment: I have no idea what "navigation view" you mean, but, no, that's what you need to return there. You're just moving the inflation to the top of the method, and returning the inflated `View` at the end, instead of inflating and returning in one line.

Comment: Would you mind pasting the following code so I can give you credit for answering

Comment: import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.ImageView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */

Comment: public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {

Comment: public MessagesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent viewIntent =
                        new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;

    }

}

Comment: Oh, I'm good. Thanks, though. This kinda turned into a little tutorial session that covered multiple things, which we're really not supposed to do. Feel free to post an answer yourself, if you like. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct in the code just change

```
Intent viewIntent= new Intent("android.content.Intent.action.VIEW",
                           Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

Hope it will work