# getting issue in fragment, has a activity working well

Tags: android

I took example ACTIVITY of showing list of two columns and tried to implement in fragment. In activity no issues raised.
In fragment app is getting crashed

newbie to android, In ADK no error it is showing, tried in different ways not working.

Error Log:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication, PID: 10662
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.fragment.FourFragment.onCreateView(FourFragment.java:36)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2831)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1608)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1601)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1569)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1874)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:2059)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Fourfragment.java:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FourFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private MovieAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_four, container, 
false);
    listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.movie_list);
    ArrayList<Movie> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
    moviesList.add(new Movie("After Earth" , "2013"));
    moviesList.add(new Movie("Baby Driver" , "2017"));
    moviesList.add(new Movie("Deadpool" , "2016"));
    moviesList.add(new Movie("Divergent" , "2014"));
    moviesList.add(new Movie("Fight Club" , "1999"));
    moviesList.add(new Movie("Jaws" , "1975"));
    moviesList.add(new Movie("Pirates of the Caribbean" , "2011"));

    mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(),moviesList);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return view;

}}
```

MovieAdapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Movie> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();

public MovieAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Movie> list) {
    super(context, 0 , list);
    mContext = context;
    moviesList = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = 
  LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

    Movie currentMovie = moviesList.get(position);


    TextView name = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
    name.setText(currentMovie.getmName());

    TextView release = (TextView) 
    listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_release);
    release.setText(currentMovie.getmRelease());

    return listItem;
  }}
```

fragmentfour.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

 tools:context="com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.
               fragment.FourFragment">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/movie_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_release"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView_name"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Comment: show your errorlog. you can get from logcat at the time of crashing (set filter to `Nofilter`)

Comment: `listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_list);`

Comment: updated with error log

Comment: @joe cherck this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment

Comment: thanks Sharif , it worked struggling from long time

Comment: @NileshRathod it's not duplicate, answers showing for duplicate marked question is showing, what i implemented before and stuck with error.