# findViewById not recognized

Tags: java, android

this is part of my function, android studio isnt recognizing the findViewById function.
can anyone please help me figure out the problem is?\

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.p1);
                p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.p2);
                if (v.getId() == R.id.btnrock) {
                    if (player1.equals("")) {
                        player1 = "rock";
                        if (p1.getText().toString().length() == 0 || p2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(c, "fill both names", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if (p1.getText().toString().equals(p2.getText().toString())&&p2.getText().toString().length()!=0) {
                            Toast.makeText(c, "use different names", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if (p2.getText().toString().length()!=0)score.setText("now "+ p2.getText());
                    }
                    else {
                        if (player1.equals("rock"))
                            score.setText("its a tie");
                        if (player1.equals("paper"))
                            score.setText(p1.getText() + " won");
                        if (player1.equals("scissors"))
                            score.setText(p2.getText() + " won");
                        if (player1.equals("lizard"))
                            score.setText(p2.getText() + " won");
                        if (player1.equals("spock"))
                            score.setText(p1.getText() + " won");
                        player1="";
                    }
```

Comment: Is this method inside Activity or a  service or DTO?

Comment: Also, please add more details of the class.

Comment: Is that code in a `Fragment`, perhaps? Have a look at [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment) then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Fragment

You have to use the View v object to access the findviewById() method 
Here is how you would get it, also note that (EditText) cast is redundant

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    p1 =  v.findViewById(R.id.p1);
                    p2 =  v.findViewById(R.id.p2);
    .
    .
    .
    .....
}
```