# Multi Tab application

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created multi tabs app in android , But I can't refer to my Xml elements in the class in picture , I have tried solution here [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) but it didn't work for me

here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CountDown">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="450dp"
        android:autofillHints="time will be here"
        android:inputType="time"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"
        tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor"
        tools:text="time" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is my main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

here is my main activity xml

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />
    
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: class handles first tab in the app]

Comment: May we suggest adding text code to the body of the question in addition to the code image.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1blWdVrziqGH68AQzKKm7N6atLqZJiE8V?usp=sharing here is the full code

Comment: To improve your chances of getting a good response we suggest that you post the code in text form like you have done in your previous post. Images are hard to read

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @abdelrahman, Thank you for updating the post. Looks like you have a potential good answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like below code.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View frag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.count_down, container, false);
   EditText time = frag.findViewById(R.id.time);
   return frag;
}
```

Comment: I don't have any error when I write code with the same style you wrote above

Comment: can you github your code,? i can help you out if you do that.

Comment: https://github.com/AbdelrahmanHamoda/Timer here it is, but some ui changes not included yet

Comment: As per mainactivty you never called countdown or stopwatch fragment

Comment: that is just root layout not fragment.

Comment: So, how can I link them to the main activity class?

Comment: https://gofile.io/d/QLy2yZ - download the project from here, compare the changes I have made

Comment: Update for other users who refer to this answer. The issue with respect to project structure, not with the issue raised in question. Be conscious of this answer.