# The name 'SuportMapFragment' does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have implemented a map into my application though on a single view. After creating a few layouts I wanted to implement a bottom navigation view which meant I had to use fragments. I have already moved my activity's code into my fragment named map_fragment, at first I wasn't sure where to use FindFragmentById but according to [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment) this should be used on the OnCreateView() lifecycle method.
My main problem now is capturing the map fragment, since I get the error The name 'SuportMapFragment' does not exist in the current context when using

```cs
    var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.gmap);
        // Was able to use FragmentManager, but it returns null...
    // var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.gmap);
        mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

Here's the full code

```cs
    public class map_fragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Create your fragment here       
        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            // Capture the Map Fragment
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, container, false);
            var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.gmap);
            //var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.gmap);
            mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);

            return view;
        }
        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap _map)
        {
            // Some other code here
        }
}
```

As requested this is my `main_activity`

```cs
   public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Initialize Xamarin Essentials for the Geolocation Service
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main_frame);
            //var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            //if (toolbar != null)
            //{
            //    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            //    SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            //    SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            //}

            bottomNavigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);

            bottomNavigation.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected;

            // Load the first fragment on creation
            LoadFragment(Resource.Id.profile_view);

        }

        private void BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadFragment(e.Item.ItemId);
        }

        void LoadFragment(int id)
        {
            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (id)
            {
                case Resource.Id.profile_view:
                    fragment = profile_fragment.NewInstance();
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.map_view:
                    fragment = map_fragment.NewInstance();
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment == null)
                return;

            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
                .Commit();
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

These are the tutorials I am using as a guide

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/

Comment: Is there a difference between SupportMapFragment and SuportMapFragment that you are referring to? Could you also please share the layout file activity_main contents? What tutorial are you trying to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the `SupportMapFragment` in a `Fragment`,you could call it like this:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.gmap).JavaCast<SupportMapFragment>();    
 if (mapFragment == null)
    {
     mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance();
     mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
    }
```

refer the SupportMapFragment in your fragment xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/gmap"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**update**(like this,we could handle `OnMapReady`):

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.gmap).JavaCast<SupportMapFragment>();    
mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: The `mapFragment` is now returning `null`, could it be related with the layout?

Comment: Did you refer to it in your layout ?

Comment: `View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, container, false);`

Comment: you check the update above,add it in your activity_main.

Comment: Only needed to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` into the layout, it is still returning `null`

Comment: Did you add the api key in your manifest ?You could create a new project just with a fragment which refer to the SupportMapFragment,see if it could display.

Comment: Yes, here's how it looks (will alter the key of course): `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="asdsad123ñbnsah{123h12" />`
I also double checked in case it was altered in the Google Developer Console and they match.

Comment: @Jeremy if you don't use map,just add some textview or button in your activity_main,could it display ?And you don't have to show your API key here, it's risky.

Comment: I have another tab which is displayed first and it works, I just removed the map fragment and it indeed works.
That is not my key hahah just a bunch of random characters I typed.

Comment: @Jeremy let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217715/1)

Comment: I noticed the `OnMapReady` callback is not being invoked, is there any reason for that?

Comment: @Jeremy As if you want to handle `OnMapReady`,we should do some changes,see the update above,we don't use `mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance();`.