# Shimmer Effect not working on Height wrap_content

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, shimmer

I'm trying to implement the shimmer effect with the Height of wrap_content but the images are not loading, I know why it is not loading the images because the imageView has wrap_content and the shimmer also has wrap_content but I want the Height Should be  wrap_content and not fixed.

After implementing a fixed height of eg 200dp in shimmer it works but after that images are not loading

I want to make it like Pinterest where the height is adjusted according to the image

**XML Files**

*post_item_container_search.xml*

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imagePostSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner" />
```

*post_item_containe_shimmer.xml*

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/imageShimmer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
android:background="#E7E7E7"
android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner" />
```

this how it looks like after adding minHeight to both or in actual imageView

[image: this how it looks like after adding minHeight to both or in actual imageView]

Comment: try out this library https://github.com/sharish/ShimmerRecyclerView

Comment: @SagarRawal It's probably because your imageview doesn't have definite size, try changing your imageview height to like 48dp for example.

Comment: @YaMiN Do you mean I have to change the size in image view or in shimmer XML?

Comment: @YaMiN ok I have tried to make shimmer height to 200dp and the shimmer is working but after that images Is not loading I know why now but the problem is I have to make the image height wrap_content because I want to make it like Pinterest  where the height is adjusted according to the mage height so if I make image height fix I will not get that the adjustable height element

Comment: Are you trying the shimmer effect inside a recyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After implementing a fixed height of eg 200dp in shimmer it works but after that images are not loading

In that case, you should probably set an absolute width/height for the `ImageView` first. Later, you can set it back to `WARP_CONTENT` if you really need to. But first you'll need an estimated/absolute width/height for the view.

```java
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
int width = bitmap.getWidth();

ShapeableImageView siv = findViewById(R.id.imagePostSearch);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = siv.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height;
params.width = width;

//To set it back to warp content or match parent:
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Comment: do I have to implement this method in search fragment java file?

Comment: Error :- int android.graphics.Bitmap.getHeight()' on a null object reference

Comment: Inside an activity or fragment of course. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment) to know how to get an id in a fragment. The bitmap is the image that you want to reload. You can use the shimmer image in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67866395/error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-int-android-graphics-bitmap-getheight please see this question of mine with the error

Answer (score 3):

By default, the wrapcontent doesn't have any size so it is 0dp you need to define 50dp or something for the height of shimmer then only you can see the shimmering.

Can refer this [blog](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-shimmer-effect-placeholder-in-android)
or try to use this

> post_item_container_search.xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/imagePostSearch"
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
         android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
         app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep `android:minHeight` for the `ImageView` as it will give you a minimum height and also `android:height` can be `wrap_content` so it grows if the image is larger than `minHeight`.

For example,

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/imageShimmer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="100dp"
android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
android:background="#E7E7E7"
android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCorner" />
```

Comment: i have tried it but then I'm not getting the adjustable height element

Comment: Did you keep the `minHeight` on both the images - actual and shimmer? What is the size of the new image?

Comment: Brother, I have tried all three possible ways  1. adding minHieght in shimmer image View .2. adding minHieght in actual imageView 3. adding minHieght to both actual imageView and shimmer imageView

Comment: ,in 1st and 3rd option images are loading but not according what I want and in 2nd images are not loading at all

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach screenshots/short video to the question showing what is happening?

Comment: I have added a photo of how it looks like when I add minHieght to shimmer image or in both

Comment: @SagarRawal your layoutManager seems like LinearLayoutManager. Use the GridLayoutManager in this solution.

Comment: I have changed to grid layout but still the issue is going on

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy view for shimmer with fixed height, make its visibility to visible and show it until the image loads, and once the image is loaded make the dummy view visibility gone.

//XML

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <shimmerView //You can use your own
            android:id="@+id/dummyShimmerView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

//dummyShimmerView visibility is visible byDefault
Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    //TODO: something on exception
                }
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    Log.d(TAG, "OnResourceReady")
                    dummyShimmerView.visibility = View.GONE
                    postImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(imgView)
```

Comment: brother can u explain the code a little bit more

Comment: @SagarRawal Please take a look