# How is one supposed to use findViewById in fragments in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

var sampleImage  = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.Tokyo,
        R.drawable.Kenya,
        R.drawable.Newyork
)
var carouselView: CarouselView? = null
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    carouselView =findViewById(R.id.carouselview)

    carouselView!!.pageCount = sampleImage.size

    carouselView!!.setImageListener(imageListener)

}

var imageListener  = ImageListener { position, imageView -> imageView.setImageResource(sampleImage
        [ position]) }
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `view.findViewById()` inside fragments for finding views.

Answer (score 0):

It is not releated to kotlin. So findViewById is a part of View, We can use findViewById if the class is extending AppCompactActivity because AppCompactActivity extends View. So Fragment doesn't extend them, We load our fragment XML from onCreateView which returns a View Instance, And we can use that View instance to call `findViewByID` 
Cut Story Short use `view.findViewById()`
[To Know more](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))