# Android: Changing selected menu item

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to change the selected menu item of a BottomNavigationView from a seperate fragment from the one that I initialize the BottomNavigationView in. I am using

```
MenuItem item = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_home);
item.setChecked(true);
```

The problem is that the navigationView is null because I am in a seperate fragment.

I am using
`navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation);` to get the id of the navigationView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here when you use `view.findViewById(R.id.navigation);`, the `view` is representing the `view` of that separate fragment, which doesn't have such a view , hence it will return null.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But when I take away the view in front of findViewById, I am getting this: `cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'UsersFragment'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment explained here.