# How do i use findViewById in a fragment instead of an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, findviewbyid

So I'm building this calculator and I used activities but now I have to use fragments instead.
I had these buttons implemented but now that I've moved them in a fragment I cant use findViewById. How can I assign the id to my variables?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [findViewById in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495898/findviewbyid-in-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use viewBinding, and if you are not comfortable with that then you should do it in onCreateView() method of your fragment. Like this,

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, container, false)
    
    val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.id_of_imageview)
    
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `onViewCreated` has a `view` parameter. You can call it on that so like `view.findViewById(R.id.text)`