# Android Studio not showing error but app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, crash

I am making a gpa calculator in a fragment of my app. The calculator, when opened, crashes the app.

Please help, there are probably many mistakes, I am a beginner in java and android. Here is my code:

```
public class WavgFragment extends Fragment {

    Activity activity = getActivity();




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EditText ela = activity.findViewById(R.id.subela);
        EditText math =  activity.findViewById(R.id.submath);
        EditText sci =  activity.findViewById(R.id.subsci);
        EditText ss =  activity.findViewById(R.id.subss);
        EditText wl =  activity.findViewById(R.id.subwl);
        Button calc =  activity.findViewById(R.id.calc);
        TextView gpa =  activity.findViewById(R.id.gpa);

        float num1 = Float.parseFloat(ela.getText().toString());
        float num2 = Float.parseFloat(math.getText().toString());
        float num3 = Float.parseFloat(sci.getText().toString());
        float num4 = Float.parseFloat(ss.getText().toString());
        float num5 = Float.parseFloat(wl.getText().toString());

        calc.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            float sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;

            float avg = sum/5;

            String avg1 = Float.toString(avg);

            gpa.setText(avg1);

        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wavg, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
}
```

there are many things to add, this is still basic, and here is my logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.coding.studentsparks, PID: 20080
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.coding.studentsparks.WavgFragment.onCreateView(WavgFragment.java:33)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Comment: In a `Fragment` you should not use `activity.findViewById()`. For the correct solution please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496013/5646962

Comment: Your zizle is misleading, Android Studio does show an error ag run-time. That a program/app that compiles can crash at run-time is normal, thus you didn't have to put into the title that an app compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are new to android studio and java, you should not write all codes in `onCreateView` instead you should write all code in `onViewCreated`.
Now moving on to your error, this occurs beacuse you are using`EditText ela = activity.findViewById(R.id.subela);`

If you are writing your code in onCreateView you should do it as follows :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wavg, container, false);
    EditText ela = v.findViewById(R.id.subela);

    // rest of your code. at the end return the view.
    return v;

}
```

I Hope this solves your problem. wish you a great coding time.