# NPE on TextView

Tags: android, xoom

Once again I'm stumped...  The following code works fine in the Android 2.2 emulator from the SDK and on my Galaxy Nexus (running 4.0.1) but I get a NPE when running the app on Xoom (Android 3.2).

```
    final TextView resNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resNum);
    System.out.println(resNum);
    resNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String num = resNum.getText().toString();
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
```

The above is in the onCreate method (among other things of course).

The NPE occurs when performing a 'read' op on resNum, i.e. the println().

Thanks

Comment: so, findViewById failed to find R.id.resNum .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null

Comment: its better if you can show full activity...

Comment: But why does it work on 2.2 and 4.0.1 but fail on 3.2???

Comment: There are multiple answers in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialer is not available on Xoom. You can find more details [in this article](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Blog/Telephony-Services-on-XOOM-and-XOOM-WiFi/ba-p/13282).

Comment: Well, that's obvious isn't it...  Many thanks for the whack with the clue bat.