# findViewById returns null. BUT WHY?

Tags: android, eclipse, findviewbyid

I have an Adroid Activity and I want to introduce a custom list view. This is my onCreate() activity method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LoadListView();

    ListView lvw = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    lvw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            // selected item
            String element = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddEntryActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("entryToEdit", element);
            long idToEdit = Long.parseLong(hEntries.get(position).toString());
            i.putExtra("idToEdit", idToEdit);
            startActivity(i);

        }
      });   

    DbAccess oDb = new DbAccess(this);
}
```

As you can see LoadListView() method is called to load listview items:

```
private void LoadListView()
{
    oDb = new DbAccess(this);
    oDb.open();

    List<cAttivita> entries = oDb.getAttivita();

    CustomListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , entries);
    ListView lvwAttivita = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lvwAttivita.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    hEntries = new HashMap();

    for(int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++)
    {
        hEntries.put(i, entries.get(i).getId());
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapter class:

```
public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId , List<cAttivita> list ) 
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, list);           
    mContext = context;
    id = textViewResourceId;
    items = list ;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View mView = v ;
    if(mView == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if(items.get(position) != null )
    {
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
        int color = Color.argb( 200, 255, 64, 64 );
            text.setBackgroundColor( color );

    }           

    return mView;
}
```

This is activity_main.xml code:

```
 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView" 
    android:textSize="20px" 
    android:paddingTop="10dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"/> 

    <ListView xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Attività"/>
```

The problem is in the line:

```
TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Why text returns null?

Comment: did you declare a listview with android.R.id.list id inside activity_main.xml?

Comment: because android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 contains android.R.id.text1, not R.id.textView

Comment: This is activity_main.xml code:
    
  <TextView  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:textSize="20px" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>    
        
    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@android:id/list"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Attività"/>

Comment: excluse me if it's confuse but i can only add comment

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null ?

Answer (score 5):

Change the following line of code inside your getView() of your CustomAdapter.

```
TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

as you are taking `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as layout it should be `android.R.id.text1` which is declared internally in Android library.

Change my line of code inside getView() and it works for you.

Comment: You are my hero! :D
Can you explain me the error? I'm new in Android dev

Comment: When there is no view with an Id then findViewById will return you null. So you got NullPointerException.

Comment: @Daniele you are using R.id.textView which refers to your project R file but the layout file you are using is of android.R so you need find the view more specifically by saying android.R.id.text1

Comment: Perfect!! I'll send you spaghetti from Italy :D :D

Comment: @Daniele Accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others