# Null Pointer Exception when setting spinner adapter

Tags: java, android

I made a spinner with two items, and i wanted to change the text color to white so i made an xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

I tried to do this to set the adapter....

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_text);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But it gives me an error! It says there's a null pointer exception at the, spinner.setAdapter(), line. I've seen other questions with people doing this and it actually working so i dont know what's going on. Here's the code for the spinner....

```
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/sEntries" />
```

The initial problem has been fixed, but now it's not showing any of the entries.

Comment: show us how you are defining your spinner in your view(xml).

Comment: I added the spinner code

Comment: Calling findViewById() too early?  Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null.

Comment: Yeah i had to move it down to another part of the code. It just doesn't show the entries now.

Comment: For testing, try create a `textViewResourceId` or `T[] objects` and include it in `ArrayAdapter(context, resourceId, textViewResourceId|T[] objects)`. Spinner does not know how to render an empty adapter properly.

Comment: I just put objects in there using the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: And what is the result? Please update your code to prevent any miscommunication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you inflating the xml layout where you defined your spinner ? That is a very common reason for NPE. You need to inflate the layout before using resources defined in it.

Comment: Thanks, I had to move it somewhere else, and it took away the error, but it's not showing the entries now.

Comment: Check if the array adapter you defined is null ?