# Get the Fragment View using findFragmentByTag dont return whit getView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

Im try getView from my fragment instantiated using `getFragmentManager.findFragmentbyTag`, see my code below:

**MyTaskFragment.java:**

Initializing my Fragment

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new newTaskFragment();
               newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "newTask");
```

inside MyTaskFragment have the DialogFragment basically this:

```
public static class newTaskFragment extends DialogFragment {
    // ..
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_task_dialog, null))
    // ..
    return builder.create();
    // ..
}
```

and also inside MyTaskFragment jave a picker:

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
              implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
```

and this is the problem(inside picker):

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("newTask");
View viewv = fragment.getView();

Button button = (Button) viewv.findViewById(R.id.choice_hour);
```

the Button above always returns null with error, the id is inside the layout `R.layout.new_task_dialog`. I don't understood.
Please someone helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You may be receiving this error if:

- Your View ID choice_hour has a typo and does not match the View ID
  you expect to find in the View hierarchy.
- There is more than one Fragment with the "newTask" ID which doesn't
  share the same layout.
- Your OnTimeSetListener is being called before your Fragment's
  onFinishInflate().
- Your OnTimeSetListener is being called before your Fragment's
  onCreateView() is called.
- Your OnTimeSetListener is being called before your Fragment is
  attached to your Activity.

See this answer for more details: [findViewByID returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null)

Comment: The first can't be because the TimePicker is called when the user click on Button inside the fragment, so the fragment load first, after the TimePicker fragment, and when happening onTimeSet i try get the Button to change the text. I dont now because get null, of your possibilities i dont see anything can be, but thanks much.

Comment: Can you confirm that calling findViewById(R.id.choice_hour); on the inflated layout in your newTaskFragment class returns the expected reference to your View?