# NullPointerException - RelativeLayout and Gradients

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout

I'm new to this so go easy :)

I'm trying edit the android:background property of a relative layout using java but I keep getting a Null Pointer Error. The drawables in the code below are gradients contained within individual .xml files. The selectors don't have any issue when I add them via the drawer_list_item.xml file.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
    public void DrawerListItem(){
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable listSelector = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.list_selector);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(listSelector);
    }
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector_dark"
        android:id="@+id/test">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

list_selector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
    </selector>
```

list_selector_dark.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/test_normal_dark" android:state_activated="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/test_pressed_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/test_pressed_dark" android:state_activated="true"/>
    </selector>
```

The LogCat:

```
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.orgbiztech.biznotes/com.orgbiztech.biznotes.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at com.orgbiztech.biznotes.MainActivity.DrawerListItem(MainActivity.java:234)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at com.orgbiztech.biznotes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    06-04 20:34:10.596: E/AndroidRuntime(12209):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: And which line is line 234?

Comment: Looks like your `getResources()` is returning `NULL`

Comment: getResourses does not return null. drawer_list_item.xml is the layout you provided as argument for setContentView ?

Comment: you need the context for ressource 
like this context.getRessource();

Comment: Try it this way

'public void DrawerListItem(){
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
        relativeLayout .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_gradient_background);
    }'

Comment: Post your `onCreate()` and mention line number 234 .

Comment: Could you show us your onCreate() method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your line numbers but it feels like "relativeLayout" is null when you call

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(listSelector);
```

That would mean that you probably call DrawerListItem() too early and your relative view hasn't been inflated yet.

Try to put a breakpoint to that line and check the value of `relativeLayout` for null or you can also just log that value before executing the line. If `RelativeLayout` is really null, make sure to call your `DrawerListItem()` only after calling `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()`.

If that doesn't help, show us your whole `onCreate()` or search for "findViewById returns null" here on SO (see e.g. [findViewByID returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null)).

By the way, method names should start with lowercase letter by convention in Java. So consider renaming `DrawerListItem()` to `drawerListItem()`