# How to stop program crashing when user does not enter a value?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, is-empty, null-check

So basically I have a problem. When the user presses the calculate button (I'm making a calculator) without entering a value the app crashes. I want it to display a message instead but I don't know how. (updated)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.waist2height); {
        //h is cm edittext 
        final EditText h = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText w = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        final EditText r = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    });

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            float height=0;
            float weight=0;
            float result=0;



            result = (float) (( weight / height ) + 0.005) ;

            if ((h.getText().toString()).equals(""))
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your height", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   float height = Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
                }
                if ((w.getText().toString()).equals(""))
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   float weight = Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());
                }


            r.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            }
```

the code below is where i have the problem

```
if ((h.getText().toString()).equals(""))
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your height", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   float height = Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
                }
                if ((w.getText().toString()).equals(""))
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   float weight = Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());
                }
```

This is the best I can come up with but it doesn't work.

Here is the LogCat (Updated)

```
    09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769): Process: com.NovaPlex.personalfitnessfree, PID: 29769
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:308)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at com.NovaPlex.personalfitnessfree.WH$2.onClick(WH.java:80)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-20 18:50:38.509: E/AndroidRuntime(29769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: please add the full code of the calculator method, and the logcat

Comment: Use `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString()){do something}`

Comment: i have added the full code

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `== null`. Assuming you've done `findviewbyid`, it cannot be null. It doesn't check for contents.

This is a simple method how to find if EditText is empty. Parameter is the EditText you want to check and it returns `true` for empty / `false` for non-empty.

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
    return etText.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0;
}
```

EDIT :

by using `android:id="@+id/someId` in xml files, we tell Android to create new resource with chosen id (in this case `someId`) in our `R.java` class. When doing `findviewbyid` we assign that value to our View.

In short if OP did something like `EditText EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFistEditText);` before and he later tries to compare it in his `if` like `(EditText1 == null)`, it's not actually getting value of text in his EditText, it's just telling him that - yes, this view was found before and it's assigned.

Comment: _"Assuming you've done findviewbyid, it cannot be null"_... Care to explain?

Comment: Again, this statement may not be correct. The method may return null in some cases (see [findViewByID returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null)). So, checking if it's null isn't redundant.

Comment: It does nothing about checking for contents of the edittext, which is the main point of the question. The edge case of `onFinishInflate()` is in my opinion quite irrelevant because there is no point in checking EditText contents if the view wasnt inflated in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can just try this, to check if value is not entered in the `EditText`.

```
if ((EditText1.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Value1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if ((EditText2.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Value2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use **`.matches("")`** instead of `.equals("")`

**UPDATE**

You have to do it like this

```
if (!(h.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   height= Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
}
```

and

```
if (!(w.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   weight= Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
if ((EditText1.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Value1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if ((EditText2.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Value2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if (!(h.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   height= Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
}
if (!(w.getText().toString()).equals(""))
{
   weight= Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());
}
```

Replace the above code instead of yours

Comment: not worked means?still the same error in Logcat?could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: sorry about that i have added in the LogCat

Comment: what is line no 92 in WH.java?

Comment: ive tried and it does not work and the same LogCat appears

Comment: what is line no 92 in WH.java?

Comment: no. 92 :     height = Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
no. 93 :     weight = Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());

Comment: Yeah thats what i said.. Replace them with the code that i said in my updated answer

Comment: ive tried that and it still doesn't work, it requests that i create a local variable, and the problem is still the same

Comment: Could you please post the new logcat

Comment: Omg!!! You have to write those separately.. They both are two different conditions..wait..i'll update my answer

Comment: this just creates more problems in my code (i think its because i needed the parsefloat to remain where it was before) but it does show the toast message when there is no value entered in the editText

Answer (score 0):

It is already said that you'd better write a method `isEmpty`.

My suggestion is rather than writing `isEmpty` write a method called `isValid` which checks if the value is a desired value i.e. integer, double etc.

This way your program wont crash when a string is entered.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(textView.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
      Toast.makeText(this , "Enter A Number" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.